# Avoid synchronized(this) in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, synchronized

Whenever a question pops up on SO about Java synchronization, some people are very eager to point out that `synchronized(this)` should be avoided. Instead, they claim, a lock on a private reference is to be preferred.

Some of the given reasons are:

- [some *evil code* may steal your lock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416183/in-java-critical-sections-what-should-i-synchronize-on#416198) (very popular this one, also has an "accidentally" variant)
- [all synchronized methods within the same class use the exact same lock, which reduces throughput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309631/what-cases-require-synchronized-method-access-in-java#309677)
- [you are (unnecessarily) exposing too much information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439302/allowing-a-method-to-lock-its-parent-object-in-java#439317)

Other people, including me, argue that `synchronized(this)` is an idiom that is used a lot (also in Java libraries), is safe and well understood. It should not be avoided because you have a bug and you don't have a clue of what is going on in your multithreaded program. In other words: if it is applicable, then use it.

I am interested in seeing some real-world examples (no foobar stuff) where avoiding a lock on `this` is preferable when `synchronized(this)` would also do the job.

Therefore: **should you always avoid `synchronized(this)` and replace it with a lock on a private reference?**

---

Some further info (updated as answers are given):

- we are talking about instance synchronization
- both implicit (`synchronized` methods) and explicit form of `synchronized(this)` are considered
- if you quote Bloch or other authorities on the subject, don't leave out the parts you don't like (e.g. Effective Java, item on Thread Safety: *Typically it is the lock on the instance itself, but there are exceptions.)*
- if you need granularity in your locking other than `synchronized(this)` provides, then `synchronized(this)` is not applicable so that's not the issue

Comment: I'd also like to point out that context is important - the "Typically it is the lock on the instance itself" bit is within a section about documenting a conditionally thread-safe class, when you're making the lock public. In other words, that sentence applies when you've already made this decision.

Comment: In the absence of internal synch, and when external synch is needed, the lock is often the instance itself, Bloch basically says. So why wouldn't this be the case for internal synch with lock on 'this' as well? (The importance of documentation is another issue.)

Comment: There is a tradeoff between extended granularity and extra CPU cache and bus requests overhead, because locking on an external Object will most probably require a separate cache line to be modified and exchanged between CPU caches (cf. MESIF and MOESI).

Comment: I think, in the world of defensive programming, you prevent bugs not by idiom but by code. When someone asks me a question, "How optimized is your synchronization?", I want to say "Very" instead of "Very, unless someone else doesn't follow the idiom".

Answer (score 140, accepted):

I'll cover each point separately.

1. > Some evil code may steal your lock (very popular this one, also has an
   >   "accidentally" variant)

   I'm more worried about *accidentally*.  What it amounts to is that this use of `this` is part of your class' exposed interface, and should be documented.  Sometimes the ability of other code to use your lock is desired.  This is true of things like `Collections.synchronizedMap` (see the javadoc).
2. > All synchronized methods within the same class use the exact same
   >   lock, which reduces throughput

   This is overly simplistic thinking; just getting rid of `synchronized(this)` won't solve the problem.  Proper synchronization for throughput will take more thought.
3. > You are (unnecessarily) exposing too much information

   This is a variant of #1.  Use of `synchronized(this)` is part of your interface.  If you don't want/need this exposed, don't do it.

Comment: 1. "synchronized" is not part of your class' exposed interface.
2. agree
3. see 1.

Comment: Essentially synchronized(this) *is* exposed because it means that external code can affect the operation of your class.  So I assert that you must document it as interface, even if the language does not.

Comment: +1 You get rid of point 2 and pull 1 and 3 together (others did that as well, seems obvious afterwards), and very interesting remark. This one is making me think. Are you saying it's on the same level as documenting a NullPointerEx, since passing in a null ref can affect the operation of a method?

Comment: Similar.  See the Javadoc for  Collections.synchronizedMap() -- the returned object uses synchronized(this) internally and they expect the consumer to take advantage of that to use the same lock for large-scale atomic operations like iteration.

Comment: In fact Collections.synchronizedMap() does NOT use synchronized(this) internally, it uses a private final lock object.

Comment: @Bas Leijdekkers: [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap-java.util.Map-) clearly specifies that the synchronization happens on the returned map instance. What’s interesting, is, that the views returned by `keySet()` and `values()` don’t lock on (their) `this`, but the map instance, which is important to get consistent behavior for all map operations. The reason, the lock object is factored out into a variable, is, that the subclass `SynchronizedSortedMap` needs it for implementing sub-maps that lock on the original map instance.

Answer (score 92):

Well, firstly it should be pointed out that:

```
public void blah() {
  synchronized (this) {
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

is semantically equivalent to:

```
public synchronized void blah() {
  // do stuff
}
```

which is one reason not to use `synchronized(this)`.  You might argue that you can do stuff around the `synchronized(this)` block.  The usual reason is to try and avoid having to do the synchronized check at all, which leads to all sorts of concurrency problems, specifically the [double checked-locking problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking), which just goes to show how difficult it can be to make a relatively simple check threadsafe.

A private lock is a defensive mechanism, which is never a bad idea.

Also, as you alluded to, private locks can control granularity.  One set of operations on an object might be totally unrelated to another but `synchronized(this)` will mutually exclude access to all of them.

`synchronized(this)` just really doesn't give you anything.

Comment: If granularity is an issue, synchronized(this) might not be applicable, true. But: the required granularity is very often exactly granularity provided by synchronized instance methods, and we do see that synchronized methods in Java are rather common.

Comment: "synchronized(this) just really doesn't give you anything." Ok, I replace it with a synchronize(myPrivateFinalLock). What does that give me? You talk about it being a defensive mechanism. What am I protected against?

Comment: You're protected against accidental (or malicious) locking of 'this' by external objects.

Comment: I don't agree at all with this answer: a lock should always be held for the shortest amount of time possible, and that's precisely the reason why you'd want to "do stuff" around a synchronized block instead of synchronizing the whole method.

Comment: Given that the stuff you do outside of the synchronized block doesn't accessed shared data, of course.

Comment: Doing stuff outside the synchronized block is always well-intentioned.  The point is that people get this wrong a lot of the time and don't even realize it, just like in the double-checked locking problem.  The road to hell is paved with good intentions.

Comment: I disagree in general with "X is a defensive mechanism, which is never a bad idea."  There is a lot of unnecessarily bloated code out there because of this attitude.

Comment: @finnw: I agree with the bloated code thing, but when you're not sure, it's better to be safe (bloated) than sorry.

Comment: [The explanation for synchronized methods from the official Java documentation](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/classes.doc.html#260369)

Comment: @Olivier I would rather make a separate synchronized method for the one part that needs synchro, than to put a synchronized(this) block around it

Comment: It's also to be noted that the first form is legal for a constructor, while the second form is not (even though it should be).

Comment: @finnw, defensive programming is always a good thing when practicing software engineering. Vague references to bloat without specifics is not helpful to novice readers; the use of a `final Object`, which makes the locking mechanism explicit and encapsulated, is not even remotely bloat.

Answer (score 61):

While you are using synchronized(this) you are using the class instance as a lock itself. This means that while lock is acquired by *thread 1*, the *thread 2* should wait.

Suppose the following code:

```
public void method1() {
    // do something ...
    synchronized(this) {
        a ++;      
    }
    // ................
}


public void method2() {
    // do something ...
    synchronized(this) {
        b ++;      
    }
    // ................
}
```

Method 1 modifying the variable *a* and method 2 modifying the variable *b*, the concurrent modification of the same variable by two threads should be avoided and it is. BUT while *thread1* modifying *a* and *thread2* modifying *b* it can be performed without any race condition.

Unfortunately, the above code will not allow this since we are using the same reference for a lock; This means that threads even if they are not in a race condition should wait and obviously the code sacrifices concurrency of the program.

The solution is to use *2* different locks for *two* different variables:

```
public class Test {

    private Object lockA = new Object();
    private Object lockB = new Object();

    public void method1() {
        // do something ...
        synchronized(lockA) {
            a ++;      
        }
        // ................
    }


    public void method2() {
        // do something ...
        synchronized(lockB) {
            b ++;      
        }
        // ................
    }

}
```

The above example uses more fine grained locks (2 locks instead one (*lockA*  and *lockB* for variables *a* and *b* respectively) and as a result allows better concurrency, on the other hand it became more complex than the first example ...

Comment: This is very dangerous.  You've now introduced a client-side (user's of this class) lock ordering requirement.  If two threads are calling method1() and method2() in a different order, they are likely to deadlock, but the user of this class has no idea that this is the case.

Comment: Granularity not provided by "synchronized(this)" is out of the scope of my question. And shouldn't your lock fields be final?

Comment: in order to have a deadlock we should perform a call from  block synchronized by A to the block synchronized by  B. daveb, you are wrong ...

Comment: There is no deadlock in this example as far as I can see. I accept it is just pseudocode  but I would use one of the implementations of java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock like java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock

Answer (score 15):

While I agree about not adhering blindly to dogmatic rules, does the "lock stealing" scenario seem so eccentric to you? A thread could indeed acquire the lock on your object "externally"(`synchronized(theObject) {...}`), blocking other threads waiting on synchronized instance methods.

If you don't believe in malicious code, consider that this code could come from third parties (for instance if you develop some sort of application server).

The "accidental" version seems less likely, but as they say, "make something idiot-proof and someone will invent a better idiot".

So I agree with the it-depends-on-what-the-class-does school of thought.

---

**Edit following eljenso's first 3 comments:**

I've never experienced the lock stealing problem but here is an imaginary scenario:

Let's say your system is a servlet container, and the object we're considering is the `ServletContext` implementation. Its `getAttribute` method must be thread-safe, as context attributes are shared data; so you declare it as `synchronized`. Let's also imagine that you provide a public hosting service based on your container implementation.

I'm your customer and deploy my "good" servlet on your site. It happens that my code contains a call to `getAttribute`.

A hacker, disguised as another customer, deploys his malicious servlet on your site. It contains the following code in the `init` method:

```
synchronized (this.getServletConfig().getServletContext()) {
   while (true) {}
}
```

Assuming we share the same servlet context (allowed by the spec as long as the two servlets are on the same virtual host), my call on `getAttribute` is locked forever. The hacker has achieved a DoS on my servlet.

This attack is not possible if `getAttribute` is synchronized on a private lock, because 3rd-party code cannot acquire this lock.

I admit that the example is contrived and an oversimplistic view of how a servlet container works, but IMHO it proves the point.

So I would make my design choice based on security consideration: will I have complete control over the code that has access to the instances? What would be the consequence of a thread's holding a lock on an instance indefinitely?

Comment: it-depends-on-what-the-class-does: if it is an 'important' object, then lock on private reference? Else instance locking will suffice?

Comment: Yes, the lock stealing scenario seems far fetched to me. Everyone mentions it, but who has actually done it or experienced it? If you "accidentally" lock an object you shouldn't, then there is a name for this type of situation: it's a bug. Fix it.

Comment: Also, locking on internal references is not free from the "external synch attack": if you know that a certain synched part of the code waits for an external event to happen (e.g. file write, value in DB, timer event) you can probably arrange for it to block as well.

Comment: Let me confess that I am one of those idiots, al beit I did it when I was young.  I thought the code was cleaner by not creating an explicit lock object and, instead, used another private final object that needed to participate in the monitor.  I did not know that the object itself did a synchronize on itself.  You can imagine the ensuing hijinx...

Answer (score 14):

It depends on the situation.
If There is only one sharing entity or more than one.

**See full working example** [here](https://github.com/rohitksingh/Multi-Threading)

A small introduction.

**Threads and shareable entities**
It is possible for multiple threads to access same entity, for eg multiple connectionThreads sharing a single messageQueue. Since the threads run concurrently there may be a chance of overriding one's data by another which may be a messed up situation.
So we need some way to ensure that shareable entity is accessed only by one thread at a time. (CONCURRENCY).

**Synchronized block**
synchronized() block is a way to ensure concurrent access of shareable entity.
First, a small analogy
Suppose There are two-person P1, P2 (threads) a Washbasin (shareable entity) inside a washroom and there is a door (lock).
Now we want one person to use washbasin at a time.
An approach is to lock the door by P1 when the door is locked P2 waits until p1 completes his work
P1 unlocks the door
then only p1 can use washbasin.

syntax.

```
synchronized(this)
{
  SHARED_ENTITY.....
}
```

"this" provided the intrinsic lock associated with the class (Java developer designed Object class in such a way that each object can work as monitor).
Above approach works fine when there are only one shared entity and multiple threads (1: N).
  [image]
**N shareable entities-M threads**
Now think of a situation when there is two washbasin inside a washroom and only one door. If we are using the previous approach, only p1 can use one washbasin at a time while p2 will wait outside. It is wastage of resource as no one is using B2 (washbasin).
A wiser approach would be to create a smaller room inside washroom and provide them one door per washbasin. In this way, P1 can access B1 and P2 can access B2 and vice-versa.

```
washbasin1;  
washbasin2;

Object lock1=new Object();
Object lock2=new Object();

  synchronized(lock1)
  {
    washbasin1;
  }

  synchronized(lock2)
  {
    washbasin2;
  }
```

[image]
[image]

**See more on Threads**----> [here](https://github.com/rohitksingh/Multi-Threading/wiki)

Answer (score 12):

**There seems a different consensus in the C# and Java camps on this.**  The majority of Java code I have seen uses:

```
// apply mutex to this instance
synchronized(this) {
    // do work here
}
```

whereas the majority of C# code opts for the arguably safer:

```
// instance level lock object
private readonly object _syncObj = new object();

...

// apply mutex to private instance level field (a System.Object usually)
lock(_syncObj)
{
    // do work here
}
```

The C# idiom is certainly safer.  As mentioned previously, no malicious / accidental access to the lock can be made from outside the instance.  Java code has this risk too, **but it seems that the Java community has gravitated over time to the slightly less safe, but slightly more terse version.**

That's not meant as a dig against Java, just a reflection of my experience working on both languages.

Comment: Perhaps since C# is a younger language, they learned from bad patterns that were figured out in the Java camp and code stuff like this better?  Are there also less singletons?  :)

Comment: He he.  Quite possibly true, but I'm not going to rise to the bait!  One think I can say for certain is that there are more capital letters in C# code ;)

Comment: Just not true (to put it nicely)

Answer (score 7):

The `java.util.concurrent` package has vastly reduced the complexity of my thread safe code. I only have anecdotal evidence to go on, but most work I have seen with `synchronized(x)` appears to be re-implementing a Lock, Semaphore, or Latch, but using the lower-level monitors.

With this in mind, synchronizing using any of these mechanisms is analogous to synchronizing on an internal object, rather than leaking a lock. This is beneficial in that you have absolute certainty that you control the entry into the monitor by two or more threads.

Answer (score 5):

If you've decided that:

- the thing you need to do is lock on
  the current object; and
- you want to
  lock it with granularity smaller than
  a whole method;

then I don't see the a taboo over synchronizezd(this).

Some people deliberately use synchronized(this) (instead of marking the method synchronized) inside the whole contents of a method because they think it's "clearer to the reader" which object is actually being synchronized on. So long as people are making an informed choice (e.g. understand that by doing so they're actually inserting extra bytecodes into the method and this could have a knock-on effect on potential optimisations), I don't particularly see a problem with this. You should always document the concurrent behaviour of your program, so I don't see the "'synchronized' publishes the behaviour" argument as being so compelling.

As to the question of which object's lock you should use, I think there's nothing wrong with synchronizing on the current object **if this would be expected by the logic of what you're doing and how your class would typically be used**. For example, with a collection, the object that you would logically expect to lock is generally the collection itself.

Comment: "if this would be expected by the logic..." is a point I am trying to get across as well. I don't see the point of *always* using private locks, although the general consensus seems to be that it is better, since it doesn't hurt and is more defensive.

Answer (score 4):

A lock is used for either *visibility* or for protecting some data from *concurrent modification* which may lead to race.

When you need to just make primitive type operations to be atomic there are available options like `AtomicInteger` and the likes.

But suppose you have two integers which are related to each other like `x` and `y` co-ordinates, which are related to each other and should be changed in an atomic manner. Then you would protect them using a same lock.

A lock should only protect the state that is related to each other. No less and no more. If you use `synchronized(this)` in each method then even if the state of the class is unrelated all the threads will face contention even if updating unrelated state.

```
class Point{
   private int x;
   private int y;

   public Point(int x, int y){
       this.x = x;
       this.y = y;
   }

   //mutating methods should be guarded by same lock
   public synchronized void changeCoordinates(int x, int y){
       this.x = x;
       this.y = y;
   }
}
```

In the above example I have only one method which mutates both `x` and `y` and not two different methods as `x` and `y` are related and if I had given two different methods for mutating `x` and `y` separately then it would not have been thread safe.

This example is just to demonstrate and not necessarily the way it should be implemented. The best way to do it would be to make it ***IMMUTABLE***.

Now in opposition to `Point` example, there is an example of `TwoCounters` already provided by @Andreas where the state which is being protected by two different locks as the state is unrelated to each other.

The process of using different locks to protect unrelated states is called *Lock Striping or Lock Splitting*

Answer (score 4):

I think there is a good explanation on why each of these are vital techniques under your belt in a book called Java Concurrency In Practice by Brian Goetz. He makes one point very clear - you must use the same lock "EVERYWHERE" to protect the state of your object. Synchronised method and synchronising on an object often go hand in hand. E.g. Vector synchronises all its methods. If you have a handle to a vector object and are going to do "put if absent" then merely Vector synchronising its own individual methods isn't going to protect you from corruption of state. You need to synchronise using synchronised (vectorHandle). This will result in the SAME lock being acquired by every thread which has a handle to the vector and will protect overall state of the vector. This is called client side locking. We do know as a matter of fact vector does synchronised (this) / synchronises all its methods and hence synchronising on the object vectorHandle will result in proper synchronisation of vector objects state. Its foolish to believe that you are thread safe just because you are using a thread safe collection. This is precisely the reason ConcurrentHashMap explicitly introduced putIfAbsent method - to make such operations atomic.

In summary

1. Synchronising at method level allows client side locking.
2. If you have a private lock object - it makes client side locking impossible. This is fine if you know that your class doesn't have "put if absent" type of functionality.
3. If you are designing a library - then synchronising on this or synchronising the method is often wiser. Because you are rarely in a position to decide how your class is going to be used.
4. Had Vector used a private lock object - it would have been impossible to get "put if absent" right. The client code will never gain a handle to the private lock thus breaking the fundamental rule of using the EXACT SAME LOCK to protect its state.
5. Synchronising on this or synchronised methods do have a problem as others have pointed out - someone could get a lock and never release it. All other threads would keep waiting for the lock to be released.
6. So know what you are doing and adopt the one that's correct.
7. Someone argued that having a private lock object gives you better granularity - e.g. if two operations are unrelated - they could be guarded by different locks resulting in better throughput. But this i think is design smell and not code smell - if two operations are completely unrelated why are they part of the SAME class? Why should a class club unrelated functionalities at all? May be a utility class? Hmmmm - some util providing string manipulation and calendar date formatting through the same instance?? ... doesn't make any sense to me at least!!

Answer (score 3):

No, you shouldn't *always*.  However, I tend to avoid it when there are multiple concerns on a particular object that only need to be threadsafe in respect to themselves.  For example, you might have a mutable data object that has "label" and "parent" fields; these need to be threadsafe, but changing one need not block the other from being written/read.  (In practice I would avoid this by declaring the fields volatile and/or using java.util.concurrent's AtomicFoo wrappers).

Synchronization in general is a bit clumsy, as it slaps a big lock down rather than thinking exactly how threads might be allowed to work around each other.  Using `synchronized(this)` is even clumsier and anti-social, as it's saying "no-one may change *anything* on this class while I hold the lock".  How often do you actually need to do that?

I would much rather have more granular locks; even if you do want to stop everything from changing (perhaps you're serialising the object), you can just acquire all of the locks to achieve the same thing, plus it's more explicit that way.  When you use `synchronized(this)`, it's not clear exactly why you're synchronizing, or what the side effects might be.  If you use `synchronized(labelMonitor)`, or even better `labelLock.getWriteLock().lock()`, it's clear what you are doing and what the effects of your critical section are limited to.

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer**: You have to understand the difference and make choice depending on the code.

**Long answer**: In general I would rather try to avoid *synchronize(this)* to reduce contention but private locks add complexity you have to be aware of. So use the right synchronization for the right job. If you are not so experienced with multi-threaded programming I would rather stick to instance locking and read up on this topic. (That said: just using *synchronize(this)* does not automatically make your class fully thread-safe.) This is a not an easy topic but once you get used to it, the answer whether to use *synchronize(this)* or not comes naturally.

Comment: Do I understand you correctly when you say it depends on your experience?

Comment: In the first place it depends on the code that you want to write. Just saying that you might need a little more experience when you divert to not use synchronize(this).

Answer (score 1):

The reason not to synchronize on *this* is that sometimes you need more than one lock (the second lock often gets removed after some additional thinking, but you still need it in the intermediate state). If you lock on *this*, you always have to remember which one of the two locks is *this*; if you lock on a private Object, the variable name tells you that.

From the reader's viewpoint, if you see locking on *this*, you always have to answer the two questions:

1. what kind of access is protected by *this*?
2. is one lock really enough, didn't someone introduce a bug?

An example:

```
class BadObject {
    private Something mStuff;
    synchronized setStuff(Something stuff) {
        mStuff = stuff;
    }
    synchronized getStuff(Something stuff) {
        return mStuff;
    }
    private MyListener myListener = new MyListener() {
        public void onMyEvent(...) {
            setStuff(...);
        }
    }
    synchronized void longOperation(MyListener l) {
        ...
        l.onMyEvent(...);
        ...
    }
}
```

If two threads begin `longOperation()` on two different instances of `BadObject`, they acquire 
their locks; when it's time to invoke `l.onMyEvent(...)`, we have a deadlock because neither of the threads may acquire the other object's lock.

In this example we may eliminate the deadlock by using two locks, one for short operations and one for long ones.

Comment: The only way in to get a deadlock in this example is when `BadObject` A invokes `longOperation` on B, passing A's `myListener`, and vice versa. Not impossible, but quite convoluted, supporting my earlier points.

Answer (score 1):

As already said here synchronized block can use user-defined variable as lock object, when synchronized function uses only "this". And of course you can manipulate with areas of your function which should be synchronized and so on.

But everyone says that no difference between synchronized function and block which covers whole function using "this" as lock object. That is not true, difference is in byte code which will be generated in both situations. In case of synchronized block usage should be allocated local variable which holds reference to "this". And as result we will have a little bit larger size of function (not relevant if you have only few number of functions).

More detailed explanation of the difference you can find here:
http://www.artima.com/insidejvm/ed2/threadsynchP.html

Also usage of synchronized block is not good due to following point of view:

> The synchronized keyword is very limited in one area: when exiting a synchronized block, all threads that are waiting for that lock must be unblocked, but only one of those threads gets to take the lock; all the others see that the lock is taken and go back to the blocked state. That's not just a lot of wasted processing cycles: often the context switch to unblock a thread also involves paging memory off the disk, and that's very, very, expensive.

For more details in this area I would recommend you read this article:
http://java.dzone.com/articles/synchronized-considered

Answer (score 1):

This is really just supplementary to the other answers, but if your main objection to using private objects for locking is that it clutters your class with fields that are not related to the business logic then Project Lombok has [`@Synchronized`](https://projectlombok.org/features/Synchronized) to generate the boilerplate at compile-time:

```
@Synchronized
public int foo() {
    return 0;
}
```

compiles to

```
private final Object $lock = new Object[0];

public int foo() {
    synchronized($lock) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the task you want to do, but I wouldn't use it. Also, check if the thread-save-ness you want to accompish couldn't be done by synchronize(this) in the first place? There are also some nice [locks in the API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/package-summary.html) that might help you :)

Answer (score 0):

A good example for use synchronized(this).

```
// add listener
public final synchronized void addListener(IListener l) {listeners.add(l);}
// remove listener
public final synchronized void removeListener(IListener l) {listeners.remove(l);}
// routine that raise events
public void run() {
   // some code here...
   Set ls;
   synchronized(this) {
      ls = listeners.clone();
   }
   for (IListener l : ls) { l.processEvent(event); }
   // some code here...
}
```

As you can see here, we use synchronize on this to easy cooperate of lengthly (possibly infinite loop of run method) with some synchronized methods there.

Of course it can be very easily rewritten with using synchronized on private field. But sometimes, when we already have some design with synchronized methods (i.e. legacy class, we derive from, synchronized(this) can be the only solution).

Comment: Any object could be used as the lock here.  It does not need to be `this`.  It could be a private field.

Comment: Correct, but the purpose of this example was to show how do proper synchronizing, if we decided to use method synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

I want to mention possible solution for atomic parts of source code. You can use a Hashmap with locks that use class names and line numbers.

```
// Synchronization objects (locks)
private static HashMap<String, Object> locks = new HashMap<String, Object>();
// Simple method
private static Object atomic() {
    StackTraceElement [] stack = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace(); // get execution point 
    StackTraceElement exepoint = stack[2];
    // creates unique key from class name and line number using execution point
    String key = String.format("%s#%d", exepoint.getClassName(), exepoint.getLineNumber()); 
    Object lock = locks.get(key); // use old or create new lock
    if (lock == null) {
        lock = new Object();
        locks.put(key, lock);
    }
    return lock; // return reference to lock
}
// Synchronized code
void dosomething1() {
    // start commands
    synchronized (atomic()) {
        // atomic commands 1
        ...
    }
    // other command
}
// Synchronized code
void dosomething2() {
    // start commands
    synchronized (atomic()) {
        // atomic commands 2
        ...
    }
    // other command
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using `synchronized(this)` as a locking mechanism: This locks the whole class instance and can cause deadlocks. In such cases, refactor the code to lock only a specific method or variable, that way whole class doesn't get locked. `Synchronised` can be used inside method level.
Instead of using `synchronized(this)`, below code shows how you could just lock a method.

```
   public void foo() {
if(operation = null) {
    synchronized(foo) { 
if (operation == null) {
 // enter your code that this method has to handle...
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My two cents in 2019 even though this question could have been settled already.

Locking on 'this' is not bad if you know what you are doing but behind the scene locking on 'this' is (which unfortunately what synchronized keyword in method definition allows).

If you actually want users of your class to be able to 'steal' your lock (i.e. prevent other threads from dealing with it), you actually want all the synchronized methods to wait while another sync method is running and so on. 
It should be intentional and well thought off (and hence documented to help your users understand it).

To further elaborate, in the reverse you must know what you are 'gaining' (or 'losing' out on) if you lock on a non accessible lock (nobody can 'steal' your lock, you are in total control and so on...).

The problem for me is that synchronized keyword in the method definition signature makes it just too easy for programmers **not to think** about what to lock on which is a mighty important thing to think about if you don't want to run into problems in a multi-threaded program.

One can't argue that 'typically' you don't want users of your class to be able to do these stuff or that 'typically' you want...It depends on what functionality you are coding. You can't make a thumb rule as you can't predict all the use cases.

Consider for e.g. the printwriter which uses an internal lock but then people struggle to use it from multiple threads if they don't want their output to interleave.

Should your lock be accessible outside of the class or not is your decision as a programmer on the basis of what functionality the class has. It is part of the api. You can't move away for instance from synchronized(this) to synchronized(provateObjet) without risking breaking changes in the code using it.

Note 1: I know you can achieve whatever synchronized(this) 'achieves' by using a explicit lock object and exposing it but I think it is unnecessary if your behaviour is well documented and you actually know what locking on 'this' means.

Note 2: I don't concur with the argument that if some code is accidentally stealing your lock its a bug and you have to solve it. This in a way is same argument as saying I can make all my methods public even if they are not meant to be public. If someone is 'accidentally' calling my intended to be private method its a bug. Why enable this accident in the first place!!! If ability to steal your lock is a problem for your class don't allow it. As simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

Let me put the conclusion first - locking on private fields does not work for slightly more complicated multi-threaded program. This is because multi-threading is a global problem. It is impossible to localize synchronization unless you write in a very defensive way (e.g. copy everything on passing to other threads).

---

Here is the long explanation:

Synchronization includes 3 parts: Atomicity, Visibility and Ordering

Synchronized block is very coarse level of synchronization. It enforces visibility and ordering just as what you expected. But for atomicity, it does not provide much protection. Atomicity requires global knowledge of the program rather than local knowledge. (And that makes multi-threading programming very hard)

Let's say we have a class `Account` having method `deposit` and `withdraw`. They are both synchronized based on a private lock like this:

```
class Account {
    private Object lock = new Object();

    void withdraw(int amount) {
        synchronized(lock) {
            // ...
        }
    }

    void deposit(int amount) {
        synchronized(lock) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Considering we need to implement a higher-level class which handles transfer, like this:

```
class AccountManager {
    void transfer(Account fromAcc, Account toAcc, int amount) {
        if (fromAcc.getBalance() > amount) {
            fromAcc.setBalance(fromAcc.getBalance() - amount);
            toAcc.setBalance(toAcc.getBalance + amount);
        }
    }
}
```

Assuming we have 2 accounts now,

```
Account john;
Account marry;
```

If the `Account.deposit()` and `Account.withdraw()` are locked with internal lock only. That will cause problem when we have 2 threads working:

```
// Some thread
void threadA() {
    john.withdraw(500);
}

// Another thread
void threadB() {
    accountManager.transfer(john, marry, 100);
}
```

Because it is possible for both `threadA` and `threadB` run at the same time. And thread B finishes the conditional check, thread A withdraws, and thread B withdraws again. This means we can withdraw $100 from John even if his account has no enough money. This will break atomicity.

You may propose that: why not adding `withdraw()` and `deposit()` to `AccountManager` then? But under this proposal, we need to create a multi-thread safe `Map` which maps from different accounts to their locks. We need to delete the lock after execution (otherwise will leak memory). And we also need to ensure no other one accesses the `Account.withdraw()` directly. This will introduce a lots of subtle bugs.

The correct and most idiomatic way is to expose the lock in the `Account`. And let the `AccountManager` to use the lock. But in this case, why not just use the object itself then?

```
class Account {
    synchronized void withdraw(int amount) {
        // ...
    }

    synchronized void deposit(int amount) {
        // ...
    }
}

class AccountManager {
    void transfer(Account fromAcc, Account toAcc, int amount) {
        // Ensure locking order to prevent deadlock
        Account firstLock = fromAcc.hashCode() < toAcc.hashCode() ? fromAcc : toAcc;
        Account secondLock = fromAcc.hashCode() < toAcc.hashCode() ? toAcc : fromAcc;

        synchronized(firstLock) {
            synchronized(secondLock) {
                if (fromAcc.getBalance() > amount) {
                    fromAcc.setBalance(fromAcc.getBalance() - amount);
                    toAcc.setBalance(toAcc.getBalance + amount);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To conclude in simple English, private lock does not work for slightly more complicated multi-threaded program.

(Reposted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/67877650/474197)

Answer (score 0):

To add to what has been mentioned earlier, with the release of Java 21, which introduced Project Loom and Virtual Threads, it's advisable to avoid `synchronized` blocks.

This is because [JEP 444](https://openjdk.org/jeps/444) and [JEP 425](https://openjdk.org/jeps/425) tell us the following:

```
There are two scenarios in which a virtual thread cannot be unmounted during blocking operations because it is pinned to its carrier:
  When it executes code inside a synchronized block or method, or
  When it executes a native method or a foreign function.
```

Thus, a virtual thread does not release the operating system thread while working with a `synchronized` method or block.

Answer (score -3):

I think points one (somebody else using your lock) and two (all methods using the same lock needlessly) can happen in any fairly large application. Especially when there's no good communication between developers.

It's not cast in stone, it's mostly an issue of good practice and preventing errors.