# How to use wait and notify in Java without IllegalMonitorStateException?

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, java-threads

I have 2 matrices and I need to multiply them and then print the results of each cell. As soon as one cell is ready I need to print it, but for example I need to print the [0][0] cell before cell [2][0] even if the result of [2][0] is ready first. So I need to print it by order.
So my idea is to make the printer thread wait until the `multiplyThread` notifies it that the correct cell is ready to be printed and then the `printerThread` will print the cell and go back to waiting and so on..

So I have this thread that does the multiplication:

```
public void run() 
{
    int countNumOfActions = 0; // How many multiplications have we done
    int maxActions = randomize(); // Maximum number of actions allowed

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {       
        result[rowNum][colNum] = result[rowNum][colNum] + row[i] * col[i];
        countNumOfActions++;
        // Reached the number of allowed actions
        if (countNumOfActions >= maxActions)
        {
            countNumOfActions = 0;
            maxActions = randomize();
            yield();
        }   
    }
    isFinished[rowNum][colNum] = true;
    notify();
}
```

Thread that prints the result of each cell:

```
public void run()
{
    int j = 0; // Columns counter
    int i = 0; // Rows counter
    System.out.println("The result matrix of the multiplication is:");

    while (i < creator.getmThreads().length)
    {
        synchronized (this)
        {
            try 
            {
                this.wait();
            } 
            catch (InterruptedException e1) 
            {
            }
        }
        if (creator.getmThreads()[i][j].getIsFinished()[i][j] == true)
        {
            if (j < creator.getmThreads()[i].length)
            {
                System.out.print(creator.getResult()[i][j] + " ");
                j++;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println();
                j = 0;
                i++;
                System.out.print(creator.getResult()[i][j] + " ");
            }
        }
    }
```

Now it throws me these exceptions:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-9" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.lang.Object.notify(Native Method)
    at multiplyThread.run(multiplyThread.java:49)
Exception in thread "Thread-6" Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.lang.Object.notify(Native Method)
    at multiplyThread.run(multiplyThread.java:49)
java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.lang.Object.notify(Native Method)
    at multiplyThread.run(multiplyThread.java:49)
Exception in thread "Thread-5" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.lang.Object.notify(Native Method)
    at multiplyThread.run(multiplyThread.java:49)
Exception in thread "Thread-8" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.lang.Object.notify(Native Method)
    at multiplyThread.run(multiplyThread.java:49)
Exception in thread "Thread-7" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.lang.Object.notify(Native Method)
    at multiplyThread.run(multiplyThread.java:49)
Exception in thread "Thread-11" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.lang.Object.notify(Native Method)
    at multiplyThread.run(multiplyThread.java:49)
Exception in thread "Thread-10" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.lang.Object.notify(Native Method)
    at multiplyThread.run(multiplyThread.java:49)
Exception in thread "Thread-12" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.lang.Object.notify(Native Method)
    at multiplyThread.run(multiplyThread.java:49)
```

line 49 in `multiplyThread` is the "notify()"..I think I need to use the synchronized differently but I am not sure how.

If anyone can help this code to work I will really appreciate it.

Answer (score 221, accepted):

To be able to call [notify()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify()) you need to synchronize on the same object.

```
synchronized (someObject) {
    someObject.wait();
}

/* different thread / object */
synchronized (someObject) {
    someObject.notify();
}
```

Comment: This is faster than custom locks such as while(otherThread.notReady){} ? Or slower?

Comment: The `while(!JobCompleted);` option is generally a bad idea because it ties up your CPU at 100% checking the same variable constantly (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1676030/57508))

Comment: `while(!JobCompleted) Thread.sleep(5); ` does not have that problem

Comment: It still has the problem of being something completely different. Polling (repeatedly checking if some condition is met, i.e. what you are doing) is generally less preferred over being notified if said condition is changed (i.e. what I outlined in the answer).

Comment: what if .wait() is used in a synchronized method? Nested scnyhronizeds are overkill?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik you can call `wait` whenever the current thread has a lock on the object on which `wait` is called. Whether you use a `synchronized` block or a synchronized method is completely up to you.

Comment: @BeniBela But it can be expected to be slower for sure (regarding Huseyin's original question).

Comment: Where's the condition we are waiting for?

Comment: There’s no condition. `wait` waits until `notify` or `notifyAll` was called on the same object.

Answer (score 64):

While using the `wait` and `notify` or `notifyAll` methods in Java the following things must be remembered:

1. Use `notifyAll` instead of `notify` if you expect that more than one thread will be waiting for a lock.
2. [The `wait` and `notify` methods must be called in a synchronized context](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/05/wait-notify-and-notifyall-in-java.html). See the link for a more detailed explanation.
3. Always call the `wait()` method in a loop because if multiple threads are waiting for a lock and one of them got the lock and reset the condition, then the other threads need to check the condition after they wake up to see whether they need to wait again or can start processing.
4. Use the same object for calling `wait()` and `notify()` method; every object has its own lock so calling `wait()` on object A and `notify()` on object B will not make any sense.

Answer (score 21):

Do you need to thread this at all ? I'm wondering how big your matrices are, and whether there's any benefit in having one thread print whilst the other does the multiplication.

Perhaps it would be worth measuring this time before doing the relatively complex threading work ?

If you do need to thread it, I would create 'n' threads to perform the multiplication of the cells (perhaps 'n' is the number of cores available to you), and then use the [ExecutorService](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) and [Future](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) mechanism to dispatch multiple multiplications simultaneously.

That way you can optimise the work based on the number of cores, and you're using the higher level Java threading tools (which should make life easier). Write the results back into a receiving matrix, and then simply print this once all your Future tasks have completed.

Comment: +1 @Greg I think you should take a look at java.util.concurrent package, as pointed out by Brian.

Comment: +1 and also check out this book which will also teach you the correct way to use wait() and notify() http://jcip.net/

Answer (score 14):

Let's say you have 'black box' application with some class named `BlackBoxClass` that has method `doSomething();`.

Further, you have observer or listener named `onResponse(String resp)` that will be called by `BlackBoxClass` after unknown time.

The flow is simple:

```
private String mResponse = null; 
 ...
BlackBoxClass bbc = new BlackBoxClass();
   bbc.doSomething();
...
@override
public void onResponse(String resp){        
      mResponse = resp;       
}
```

Lets say we don't know what is going on with `BlackBoxClass` and when we should  get answer but you don't want to continue your code till you get answer or in other word get `onResponse` call. Here enters 'Synchronize helper':

```
public class SyncronizeObj {
public void doWait(long l){
    synchronized(this){
        try {
            this.wait(l);
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
}

public void doNotify() {
    synchronized(this) {
        this.notify();
    }
}

public void doWait() {
    synchronized(this){
        try {
            this.wait();
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
}
}
```

Now we can implement what we want:

```
public class Demo {

private String mResponse = null; 
 ...
SyncronizeObj sync = new SyncronizeObj();

public void impl(){

BlackBoxClass bbc = new BlackBoxClass();
   bbc.doSomething();

   if(mResponse == null){
      sync.doWait();
    }

/** at this momoent you sure that you got response from  BlackBoxClass because
  onResponse method released your 'wait'. In other cases if you don't want wait too      
  long (for example wait data from socket) you can use doWait(time) 
*/ 
...

}


@override
public void onResponse(String resp){        
      mResponse = resp;
      sync.doNotify();       
   }

}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can only call notify on objects where you own their monitor. So you need something like

```
synchronized(threadObject)
{
   threadObject.notify();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

`notify()` needs to be synchronized as well

Answer (score 3):

I'll right simple example show you the right way  to use `wait` and `notify` in Java.
So I'll create two class named **ThreadA** & **ThreadB**. ThreadA will call ThreadB.

```
public class ThreadA {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ThreadB b = new ThreadB();//<----Create Instance for seconde class
        b.start();//<--------------------Launch thread

        synchronized(b){
            try{
                System.out.println("Waiting for b to complete...");
                b.wait();//<-------------WAIT until the finish thread for class B finish
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println("Total is: " + b.total);
        }
    }
}
```

and for Class ThreadB:

```
class ThreadB extends Thread{
    int total;
    @Override
    public void run(){
        synchronized(this){
            for(int i=0; i<100 ; i++){
                total += i;
            }
            notify();//<----------------Notify the class wich wait until my    finish 
//and tell that I'm finish
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple use if you want How to execute threads alternatively :-

```
public class MyThread {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Object lock = new Object();
        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                synchronized (lock) {
                    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
                        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ":" + "A");
                        lock.notify();
                        lock.wait();
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {}
        }, "T1").start();

        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                synchronized (lock) {
                    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
                        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ":" + "B");
                        lock.notify();
                        lock.wait();
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {}
        }, "T2").start();
    }
}
```

> response :-

```
T1:A
T2:B
T1:A
T2:B
T1:A
T2:B
T1:A
T2:B
T1:A
T2:B
T1:A
T2:B
```

Comment: How does this work when I have 4 operations to perform in a synchronous way?

Answer (score 2):

we can call notify to resume the execution of waiting objects as

```
public synchronized void guardedJoy() {
    // This guard only loops once for each special event, which may not
    // be the event we're waiting for.
    while(!joy) {
        try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
    System.out.println("Joy and efficiency have been achieved!");
}
```

resume this by invoking notify on another object of same class

```
public synchronized notifyJoy() {
    joy = true;
    notifyAll();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this particular problem, why not store up your various results in variables and then when the last of your thread is processed you can print in whatever format you want. This is especially useful if you are gonna be using your work history in other projects.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a situation for producer-consumer pattern. If you’re using java 5 or up, you may consider using blocking queue(java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue) and leave the thread coordination work to the underlying framework/api implementation.
See the example from
java 5:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html
or java 7 (same example):
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html

Answer (score 0):

You have properly guarded your code block when you call `wait()` method by using `synchronized(this)`.

But you have not taken same precaution when you call `notify()` method without using guarded block : `synchronized(this)` or `synchronized(someObject)`

If you refer to oracle documentation page on [Object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) class, which contains `wait()` ,`notify()`, `notifyAll()` methods, you can see below precaution in all these three methods

> This method should only be called by a thread that is the owner of this object's monitor

Many things have been changed in last 7 years and let's have look into other alternatives to `synchronized` in below SE questions:

[Why use a ReentrantLock if one can use synchronized(this)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821801/why-use-a-reentrantlock-if-one-can-use-synchronizedthis/36827191#36827191)

[Synchronization vs Lock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201713/synchronization-vs-lock/34267717#34267717)

[Avoid synchronized(this) in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442564/avoid-synchronizedthis-in-java/36692190#36692190)