# To make a choice between ManualResetEvent or Thread.Sleep()

Tags: c#, multithreading, sleep, manualresetevent

I am not sure which strategy to adopt...I am focusing on my operation getting completed, but I'd also like to keep performance issues to a min too...there is a method called **Execute()** which has to wait (run synchronously) until an operation completes. This operation happens on another thread. There are 2 ways to implement the same thing...

By using ManualResetEvent

```
void Execute()
{
    taskHandle = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    .
    .
    //delegate task to another thread
    .
    .
    taskHandle.WaitOne();
}
```

## OR

By using a simple while construct

```
void Execute()
{
    .
    .
    //delegate task to another thread
    .
    .
    while (!JobCompleted)
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

Which one of the two approaches should I adopt...why?

EDIT:

Q2. What if I just had an empty while contruct? Whats the difference...?

```
while(!JobCompleted);
```

EDIT: (something I gathered before)

http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/waithandles.shtml - This article says manualresets are comparitively slower because they go out of managed code and back in...

Comment: Just want to point out Thread.Sleep(0) usage. Specify zero (0) to indicate that this thread should be suspended to allow other waiting threads to execute. In this case Sleep(0) is better than Sleep(1000), but using WaitHandle is still more appropriate though.

Comment: The empty while loop is basically a spinwait- it will completely consume a CPU. Not recommended.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Out of curiosity, why `ManualResetEvent` and not `AutoResetEvent`? Either way, go with the OS primitive over a sleep-check-sleep approach.

You could also use a `Monitor` lock (either explicitly through `Monitor.Enter` and `Monitor.Exit`, or through a `lock` block), but the approach should be based upon what you're actually doing; if it's a scenario of "there's only one of these *things* and I need exclusive access", then use a `Monitor` lock. If it's "I need to wait until *the other thread finishes* for reasons other than resource access", then use an `AutoResetEvent` or `ManualResetEvent`.

The suggestions to use `Thread.Join` are good if (and only if)

1. You have access to the other `Thread` object
2. You don't want to execute until the *other thread terminates*.

If either isn't true (you don't have access, or the other thread won't terminate, it will just signal an "all clear") then `Thread.Join` isn't viable.

The worst option is

`while(!JobCompleted);`

As that will tie up the processor with needless checks of the variable without any pause in between them. Yes, it will block your thread until the operation completes, but you'll max out CPU usage (or at least a single core's worth).

Comment: read somewher tht manual resets work in kernel mode...if so then there should be a performance overhead, right? PS: I've edited the question again...

Comment: You suggest going with the OS primitive, but you really should explain why.

Answer (score 4):

The event makes more efficient use of the processors- you're not having to wake the parent thread up to poll. The kernel will wake you up when the event fires.

Comment: But arent' manualResetevents expensive when compared to the other construct. I use .net 2.0. Read somewhere tht manual resets work in kernel mode where as its monitor alternatives work in user mode...so extra overhead due change of mode...! Is this true?

Comment: They are more expensive to create than Monitors, but they're also more fully featured. It depends on how frequently you're creating them. If you're looking to run thousands of these a second, a lighter-weight approach would be better.

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to the original Thread object, or can get that access, you're best off using [`Thread.Join()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95hbf2ta.aspx).

Edit: Also, if this is taking place in a GUI like WinForms or WPF, you may want to consider using [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)

Comment: Then use ManualResetEvent as @nitzmahone suggests. Or find a way to get that Thread. The only drawback with using ManualResetEvent is that both the caller and the worker have to use it, creating a possibly unwanted dependency.

Comment: @Randolpho. Wouldn't both methods have to share resource to be able to signal each other? In the case of the while loop both threads have to know about the 'JobCompleted' boolean.

Answer (score 2):

The main disadvantage to using `Thread.Sleep()` is that you are making the decision on how long the thread will wait.  The operation you are waiting for may take **more** or **less** time, and in general, it is very difficult to precisely quantify that time.  If the thread sleeps too long, then you are not making best use of system resources.

In order to be optimal, you should use `ManualResetEvent` (or `AutoResetEvent`) so that your thread is resumed as soon as the dependent operation finishes.

Answer (score 1):

ManualResetEvent is definitely the way to go.

From the code snippet you supplied, it looks like you are delegating the execution within your Execute method.  If this is the case, and you are only delegating a single task, why are you delegating to another thread at all if you have to wait for the response?  You may as well just execute the process synchronously.

Answer (score 1):

> manualresets are comparitively slower because they go out of managed code and back in..

They are probably slower than say a **[Wait/Pulse combo](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx#_Signaling_with_Wait_and_Pulse), which you should use here in my opinion**. But `Manual/AutoResetEvents` will be way faster than any `Thread.Sleep(x)` that you do, even if you choose `x = 1`. And even if you lower the Windows timer resolution to 1ms.

> What if I just had an empty while contruct? Whats the difference...?

Then one core will spin at 100% until the condition turns true, stealing away time from other threads that might instead use it to do something useful, like calculating frames for "Angry Birds" - or the cpu could simply cool off a bit, delaying the dire effects of global warming for some further nanoseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Both approaches do the same thing basically. The while loop is little bit more explicit however, since you can specify the sleep time. Although I would use the XXXResetEvent classes which are meant to be used in the scenario your working in. I would assume the threading classes would be implemented now or later with more robust threading code to handle maybe thread affinity on multi core processors.

Comment: A ManualResetEvent behaves quite differently than periodically polling.