# Java Thread.wait() warnings

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, wait

When i enclose Thread.wait() in a while loop my IDE (NetBeans) tells me that this may cause perfomance issues, how can it and is there a way arround it?

Example:

```
    while (timing){
        Thread.wait(10);
        foo++;
        }
    //Started in a seperate thread before activating.
```

EDIT: Thanks for the help, I will try to use the 'ScheduledExecutorService' instead!

Comment: Same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3956512/java-performance-issue-with-thread-sleep

Comment: Give more background, it is difficult to say if it would be better to sleep or to wait without more information...

Comment: Class `Thread` does not have a static method `wait`. I hope you have not declared a variable named `Thread`. Are we talking about the same `java.lang.Thread` or is your Thread another class?

Comment: In something like a game-loop, a delay of 10ms should be OK. The question linked by NickL contains more information on the cases where such a sleep CAN cause performance issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably wanted to just make the thread `sleep`, and that is the name of the method you needed to call.

You called `Object#wait()`, which is a *thread coordination* method, and you used an explicit timeout on it (a rather short one). My guess is that NetBeans is warning you about that timeout because normally we use `Object#wait` without a timeout, and if we use the timeout, we don't `wait` in a loop.

Now, NetBeans will also warn you about using `Thread.sleep()` in a loop because normally, if you want to schedule a repeated task (that is what you are doing), you will use a `ScheduledExecutorService`. That service is able to serve a lot of different scheduled tasks around your application, all with a single thread. Writing `Thread.sleep()` explicitly in a loop needlessly hogs a whole thread (a heavyweight system resource) to do nothing but sleep most of the time.