# Asynctask inner class not updating UI textview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I have the following code which should update UI textview on Asynctask:

```
public class HelloWorldActivity extends Activity
{
    private static TextView txtview;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        txtview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mainview);
    }

    private static class SimpleTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... res) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1500);
            } catch(InterruptedException exception) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void params) {
            txtview.setText("Hola Mundo");
        }

    }
}
```

Particularly I'm triying to change `Hello World` to `Hola Mundo` after 1,5 seconds passed. The problem is that while running the app the text still is `Hello World` and doesn't change. I get no error of any sort. I have even set `txtview` value outside `onCreate` method to avoid any access problems (or so I think).

If after `txtview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mainview);` I do `txtview.setText("Hola Mundo");` then it works flawlessly.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Where you are calling AsyncTask ?

Comment: write
new SimpleTask().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR);
below line..
 txtview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mainview);
below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not called ASyncTask, execute it like this after initializing TextView:

```
txtview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mainview);
SimpleTask objSimpleTask=new SimpleTask();
objSimpleTask.execute();
```

Hope is what you want.

Comment: It throws a `cannot find symbol` error but `SimpleTask objSimpleTask = new SimpleTask(); objSimpleTask.execute();` works nonetheless. Still a great answer to understand the call should be put in the `onCreate` method.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited the answer so can be helpful to others.

Answer (score 1):

Forget to execute `AsyncTask` by calling `AsyncTask.execute()` method. do it as by adding following lines in `onCreate` method after initializing `txtview` TextView object:

```
SimpleTask objSimpleTask=new SimpleTask();
objSimpleTask.execute();
```

Comment: At first I put it on the main class and it threw a `<identifier> expected` error but your in-depth answer removed my doubt. It works, thanks! I'll upvote you sooner or later :)

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are **forget to call AsyncTask**.

But i think it is a **bad practice** to use **AsyncTask & Thread.sleep() to update UI** .

ou can simply **do it with Handler**.

```
Runnable updateUI;
Handler h = new Handler();
```

---

```
                    updateUI=new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                        txtview.setText("Hola Mundo");

                        }
                    };

                    h.postDelayed(updateUI,1500);
```

Comment: Can you explain why it's bad practice to use AsyncTask & Thread.sleep() to update UI? do you have any articles I can read that explain it? Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3956512/java-performance-issue-with-thread-sleep

Comment: http://blogs.msmvps.com/peterritchie/2007/04/26/thread-sleep-is-a-sign-of-a-poorly-designed-program/

Comment: Interesting. I'm now going to make use of Runnables and your links helped me research further the topic. One more question if you don't mind.. should I put the `Runnable` inside `onCreate` and it's going to create a thread that doesn't interfere with UI thread? I'm putting `h.postDelayed(updateUI,1500);` inside `onCreate` and everything else in the main class `HelloWorldActivity` but it gives error `<identifier> expected [javac] updateUI=new Runnable() {`

Comment: I had to add `import android.os.Handler` and putting everything inside `onCreate` now works.

Comment: @gizko feel free to accept the answer if you are satisfied with my answer