# Java, multiple threads with only one executing at a time

Tags: java, multithreading, critical-section

I am working on an assignment and have to create two classes, one represents a person, and the other representing a bridge. Only one person can be "crossing" the bridge at any one time, but there could be people waiting to cross

I easily implemented this with multi-threading allowing for multiple people to cross at once, but I am having issues when changing it to allow only one thread to run...

My main problem is the class design they want, I have to begin the threads within the person class, but the bridge class needs to be able to wait and notify them to start/stop

Any ideas how I can do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want to read up on `wait` and `notify`. There are tutorials with a google search.

But after you understand them a bit, you want to have the person objects call `wait`. Then you want the bridge object to call `notify`. When a person object returns from `wait`, it is their turn to cross (as I understand your problem.) When the person crosses, the bridge object would call `notify` again.

Make sure you `synchronize` correctly. The tutorials should help.

Read this question as well: [How to use wait and notify in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886722/how-to-use-wait-and-notify-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

Lock an object like this:

```
// Bridge.java

public class Bridge {
private Object _mutex = new Object();

    public void cross(Person p)
        synchronized(_mutex) { 
             // code goes here
        }     
    }
}
```

That is one, probably the easiest, method..

EDIT:

even easier:

```
public class Bridge {
    public synchronized void cross(Person p)
    {
        // code goes here
    }
}
```

Comment: Using a synchronized method seems to be the most elegant Java solution possible. The asker can see ["Synchronized Methods"](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html) for a description of what all it does. It won't teach anyone much about semaphores or mutexes/conditions, but it's the instructor's own fault for selecting something as high-level as Java to teach something as low-level as synchronizing access between multiple threads.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what the assignment is asking you to do is to use (or implement) a mutex for access to the shared resource, aka the bridge.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutex

Answer (score 0):

Try java.util.concurrent:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor%28%29

This class wil produce an ExecutorService, where you can submit yout "Persons". And the Jobes are queued, one Person will cross at time.

Comment: After reading yout post again, I'm not sure, if you can chachge your design, to you this Features.