# In Java, synchronized block can synchronize on any object reference?

Tags: java

I was wondering if there is a situation where this statement will be true and needed. All the examples I have seen only synchronize on the "this" reference. Can someone tell me how a block of code in one object can be synchronized on any other reference apart from this ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes the statement is true.

There are several reasons why one would want NOT to use an intrinsic monitor (`synchronized(this)`) - one of these reasons is that it can create liveness issues - in the code below, B uses an instance of A as a lock, maybe to control access to that variable. If another thread uses that same instance of A and tries to run `a.methodA()`, it will be blocked until `methodB()` is over.

So using an intrinsic monitor exposes the synchronization policy and can lead to subtle bugs and performance issues.

```
public class A {

    public synchronized void methodA() {}

}

public class B {
    A a = new A();
    public void methodB() {
        synchronized(a) {
            // do something a little long
        }
    }
    public A getA() {return a;}
}
```

If A had used an internal monitor that problem would not be possible.

```
public class A {
    private final Object lock = new Object();

    public void methodA() {
        synchronized(lock) {}
    }

}
```

Another scenario where using ad hoc monitors makes sense is when a class contains 2 (or more) unrelated objects, that both need to be accessed in a synchronized manner. Using 2 monitors instead of one reduces contention as the 2 objects can now be accessed concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, you can use `synchronized` constructs to create instrinsic locks on any object reference, yes. Read the relevant [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html).

The immediate example of **not** using `synchronized` with this is when synchronizing on the `Class` object, which is [how `static synchronized` methods work](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.6). In reality, there are plenty of valid uses. You may want to avoid using `synchronized (this)` in favor of an internal implementation lock as otherwise you are setting a restriction that you use the lock internally, which other code you're not aware of might violate.

You should know, however, that often times you can replace `synchronized` usage with a `ReentrantLock`. You can read more about this in [my post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821801/why-use-a-reentrantreadwritelock-if-one-can-use-synchronizedthis/11821900#11821900).

Comment: Intrinsic... always forget the term.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be done.

The synchronize block will use that object as a lock, rather than the whole class.  People that use synchronized(this) { } put an exclusive lock on the whole object, which might be what you want.  However, you might have something like a persister, which is the only thing that needs to be synchronized.  synchronized(persister) { }, would provide a less granular way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SyncTest{
    private Object obj = new Object();

    public void func1() {
        synchronized(obj) {
            obj.something();
        }
}
```

Comment: Just make sure that you're using a complex enough Object.  Trying to synchronize on a type like Boolean won't do what you think it will because of how it is actually handled internally.

Comment: And make the lock final, just to be sure.