# Java Multithread Access Static Variable

Tags: java, multithreading, static

How can I access static variable from many  thread simultaneously.

If I have a class like

```
Class A {
    public static boolean FLG=false;
    .....................
    ....................
}
```

And I need to access the value from thread 1 like

```
....................
public void run() {
    boolean t1=A.FLG;
    ..................
}
```

and from thread 2 I need to set value like

```
....................
public void run() {
    A.FLG=true;
    ..................
}
```

Does this cause memory violation ?. If so what is the recommended method to handle such a situation?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap the static variable in a synchronized method and call the method as you like

```
public static synchronized void method1(){
//Whatever
}

public static synchronized void method2(){
//Whatever again
}
```

Note that there are other ways to synchronize access to a method. They are considered more efficient in environments busy threads accessing the same methods.

Check the [ReentrantLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) class. There are also answers for [when to use synchronized and RentrantLock](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11821900/897041) and many more information that could be found through google.

Also as `peter`'s answer and `muel`'s comment suggests. Marking the `boolean` variable as volatile should be helpful. `volatile` boolean variables will **NOT** cache it's initial value (`false` or `true`). The JVM could do that occasionally which could be unexpected by the programmer.

Comment: Why not just use volatile?

Comment: If the variable is used exactly as it can be seen in the code sample. The field can even be totally unprotected. Thread 2 will set its value, and Thread 1 will eventually see that change. If reading stale values is acceptable, `volatile` can be omitted, as writes to booleans are atomic on 32 bit platforms.

Comment: Which code sample do you mean ?
`Thread 2...that change`: What do you mean ?

Answer (score 5):

If all you want to do is get and set a primitive you can make it `volatile` and it will be thread safe for those operations.

Comment: I need to access the value as well as set the value

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I think it's true that ["the `volatile` keyword in Java is poorly documented, poorly understood, and rarely used"](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_volatile.shtml).
Anyway, [looks like](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7943472/56285) `volatile` is not completely equivalent to making the accessors to the field `synchronized`.

Answer (score 1):

In Class A , you can create a set and get method for FLG  like:

```
public static synchronized boolean getFlag()
{
return FLG;
}

public static synchronized setFlag(boolean flag)
{
FLG=flag;
}
```

Now from other Threads, access value of `FLG` usng this method. This will keep the value of `FLG` Consistent across multiple Threads.

Comment: What about setting FLG can I follow the same

Answer (score 1):

You may get some undesired situation where two threads try to set different values into the static variable and you won`t have sure what exactly value really is there. The best way (thinking in a simple scenario) I think it is using AtomicBoolean ( http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html ) and you get the value in the object and use it (instead of using the object all the time, due a different thread can change it and you might get unexpected scenario).

Another suggestion is to use Byteman to create concurrent tests.

Regards,
Luan

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use synchronized, ReentrantLock,
you can write your own logic for this.

Example:

```
public class A extends Thread{

    public static boolean FLG=false;

    public A(String threadName) {
        start();
        setName(threadName);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        while(true){
            if(this.getName().equals("getterThread") && FLG == true){
                boolean t1=A.FLG;
            }
            if(this.getName().equals("setterThread") && FLG == false){
                A.FLG = true;
            }
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        A dad = new A("getterThread");
        A son = new A("setterThread");
    }
}
```