# Is using ReentrantLock reliable as synchronized?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, reentrantlock

I searched a lot but was confused with the process of **'ReentrantLock'** and normal **'synchronized'** .

For example(**1**):

```
Object obj = new Object();

synchronized(obj){
//lock is guaranteed to be acquired 
}
```

example(**2**)

```
Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
lock.lock(); //problem here
try{
//dostuff
}
finally{
lock.unlock();
}
```

My question is:

In example **1**: it is guaranteed to acquire a lock on the object using the synchronized keyword.

But

In example **2**: *is it guaranteed that the lock will be acquired using the **lock.lock()** method?? or will the thread proceed to the next line for the execution?? without acquiring the lock.*

I doubt it because, using threads had resulted in unexpected outcomes for me many times.

Comment: Isn't this the whole rationale for using Lock objects? To have an unambiguous lock object, one without any other purpose and that functions well.

Comment: this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821801/why-use-a-reentrantlock-if-one-can-use-synchronizedthis

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only one thread will acquire the lock: this is the contract of `ReentrantLock`.

Therefore your example 2 is perfectly thread safe.

Comment: Does that means the lock.lock() method will acquire the lock for a particular thread for guaranteed? or is there chances that the lock cant be acquired? .

Comment: it's guaranteed.  it will wait if necessary.