# How to make object visible and editable to all threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, blockingqueue

I have written this code, an implement of blocking queue:

```
public class MyBlockingQueue extends Thread{

 final private List <Integer> queue;

  public MyBlockingQueue(){
      queue = new LinkedList<Integer>();
  }

  public synchronized int size () {

            return queue.size();

  }

  public synchronized void enqueue(int num)
  throws InterruptedException  {

    this.queue.add(num);
    System.out.println(getName()+" "+num+" added");
    notify();
  }

  public synchronized int dequeue()
  throws InterruptedException{
      while(queue.size() == 0)
          wait();

    return this.queue.remove(0);
  }
```

1.I have tried to make two threads and force them to add some number to the queue and then remove it. Unfortunatley, it seems like each thread has its own object. how can I change the code so both threads will handle the same object and add/remove to the same blocking queue synchronously?

2.Have I write the dequeue function correctly (so that when one thread removes the last number from the queue and the queue size is now zero, other threads will wait until the enqueue will notify them ) ?

this is my tester:

```
public class Main  {
    //checks the blocking queue
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    final MyBlockingQueue mine = new MyBlockingQueue();
    Thread t1 = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try {


                mine.enqueue((int)(Math.random()*1000));
                System.out.println(getName()+"<- enter");

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            };
        }
    };

    Thread t2 = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try {


                mine.dequeue();
                System.out.println(getName()+"<-remove");

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    Thread t3 = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try {


                mine.dequeue();
                System.out.println(getName()+"<-remove");

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    Thread t4 = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try {

                mine.enqueue((int)(Math.random()*1000));
                System.out.println(getName()+"<-enter");


                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    Thread t5 = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try {

                mine.dequeue();
                System.out.println(getName()+"<-remove");


                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };


    Thread t6 = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            System.out.println("thread 6 of entering began, should release last thread of remove");
            try {

                mine.enqueue((int)(Math.random()*1000));
                System.out.println(getName()+"<-enter");


                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    Thread t7 = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try {

                mine.dequeue();
                System.out.println(getName()+"<-remove");


                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    Thread t8 = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try {

                mine.dequeue();
                System.out.println(getName()+"<-remove");


                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    Thread t9 = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try {

                mine.dequeue();
                System.out.println(getName()+"<-remove");


                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    Thread t10 = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try {

                mine.dequeue();
                System.out.println(getName()+"<-remove");


                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    Thread t11 = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            System.out.println("thread 11 come to help, this comment before entering, after that we should see one add one remove");
            try {

                mine.enqueue((int)(Math.random()*1000));
                System.out.println(getName()+"<-enter");


                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t3.start();
    Thread.sleep(5000);

    t4.start();//will the remove wai for the enter
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    /////4 tries to remove, one enter
    t5.start(); //requesting to remove before have something
    t7.start();
    t8.start();
    t9.start();
    t10.start();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    t6.start();
    Thread.sleep(20000);//after 20 sec, t11 come to help
    t11.start();

}

}
```

here is the output:

```
   Thread-0 enqueued 1
Thread-1<- enter
Thread-0 dequeued 1
Thread-2<-remove
Thread-0 enqueued 4
Thread-0 dequeued 4
Thread-3<-remove
Thread-4<-enter
thread 6 of entering began, should release last thread of remove
Thread-0 enqueued 6
Thread-0 dequeued 6
Thread-5<-remove
Thread-6<-enter
thread 11 come to help, this comment before entering, after that we should see one add one remove
Thread-0 enqueued 11
Thread-0 dequeued 11
Thread-8<-remove
Thread-11<-enter
```

Comment: Why `extends Thread`?  A queue is not a kind of thread.

Comment: Re, "It seems like each thread has its own object. how can I change the code so both threads will handle the same object?"  You have not shown us any code that uses your `MyBlockingQueue` class, so it's hard to say what might or might not be wrong with that code.

Comment: sorry, I attached a test code

Comment: Please, show us the print results. For what I can see, your code is correct. (You should remove extends Thread, and the dequeue function has a problem, but all of that would still work on your test case)

Comment: I have attached it

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the queue static or pass the object to the threads upon initialization. If you don't do that the two threads will enque/dequeue on separate queues.

Comment: what should I turn to static- the list or the blocking queue?

Comment: @Limmen has written exactly what should be static queue inside your MyBlockingQueue class

Comment: oh sorry, queue is my list. I have not noticed that. thank you!

Comment: @adi, An object (e.g., a `List` or a `MyBlockingQueue`) can not be `static`.  Only a _variable_ can be static.  @Limmen is telling you to store a reference to a `MyBlockingQueue` object in a static variable, and then write code for your threads that uses that variable.

Answer (score -1):

For example:

```
public class MyBlockingQueue extends Thread {

    final private static List<Integer> queue = new LinkedList<Integer>();

    public synchronized int size() {

        return MyBlockingQueue.queue.size();

    }

    public synchronized void enqueue(int num) throws InterruptedException {

        MyBlockingQueue.queue.add(num);
        System.out.println(getName() + " enqueued " + num);
        notify();
    }

    public synchronized int dequeue() throws InterruptedException {
        while (MyBlockingQueue.queue.size() == 0) {
            wait();
        }
        System.out.println(getName() + " dequeued " + MyBlockingQueue.queue.get(0));
        return MyBlockingQueue.queue.remove(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that I have suceed managing it In other way, but thank you!! By the way,  is your code  managing the problem  that 
 "when one thread removes the last number from the queue and the queue size is now zero, other threads will wait until the enqueue will notify them"?

Comment: Its not mine, it is just your code with recommended above modifications. Good and right examples you can find in the source of the next files:    ArrayBlockingQueue
DelayQueue
LinkedBlockingQueue
PriorityBlockingQueue
SynchronousQueue. Within java.util.concurrent package

Comment: Should the size() function be syncronized? if it does, how can I make it syncroonized without writing the syncronized keyword?

Comment: Pay attention as james large wrote "A queue is not a kind of thread". You can do not synchronize size() and use AtomicInteger count variable instead for persisting a size. Also instead of synchronized you can use ReentrantLock, here you can get an explanation [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821801/why-use-a-reentrantlock-if-one-can-use-synchronizedthis)