# Confused java ThreadPool and ReentrantLock

Tags: java, multithreading, reentrantlock

I get a fixed number of two threads, then submitted 100 tasks, inside which I

used a lock and intentionally leave it unlocked, running result of this code is

sorted number from 1 to 99, this makes me confused:

1) Is it because the thread is reused so that the same thread can acquire it multiple times?

2) If so, lock does not block thread, it still can be reused? What the lock guards is only the lines within its scope.

Please correct me.

```
public class LockTest {

    public static volatile int a = 1;

    static final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

        for (int k = 0; k < 100; k++) {
            executorService.submit(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    lock.lock();
                    System.out.println(a++);
                }
            });
        }
        executorService.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is there no unlock call? What is the point of a lock that is never unlocked?

Comment: @Sidias-Korrado  yeah, I leave it unlocked, I just want to figure out how it works

Comment: You leave it locked, not unlocked.

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821801/why-use-a-reentrantlock-if-one-can-use-synchronizedthis , hope it answers your question

Comment: It does not, there is a `unlock()` call.

Answer (score 2):

If you modify your code this way you get all the information required to answer your questions by yourself:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ExecutorService executorService = newFixedThreadPool(2);
    for (int k = 0; k < 100; k++) {
        executorService.submit(() -> {
            lock.lock();
            System.out.println(currentThread().getId() +
                             " hold count: " + lock.getHoldCount());
            System.out.println("a = " + a++);
        });
    }
    executorService.shutdown();
}
```

**Output Sample**

```
12 hold count: 1
a = 1
12 hold count: 2
a = 2
12 hold count: 3
a = 3
...
12 hold count: 98
a = 98
12 hold count: 99
a = 99
```

As you can see:

- you want to output `100` numbers but you do output only `99`.
- the output shows that only one thread is working, because you never release the lock the first thread obtained. The second thread wait for obtaining the lock.
- because you use a `ReentrantLock` the first thread which obtained the lock may continue working, because he already owns the lock.
- the *JVM* will never shutdown, because the first thread will never release the lock and hence the second thread waits forever.

**Answer for question asked by PO in comment**

It is kind of predictable: the `CachedThreadPool` will create new `Threads` on the fly as required. What happens is:

- the first thread will obtain the lock forever (because it never releases it). It will process submitted tasks as fast as it can.
- while the first thread is processing, the `CachedThreadPool` will create new threads to execute the remaining tasks submitted but not yet processed.
- depending on the speed of the first thread, which obtained the lock, processing submitted tasks which are not already scheduled to other threads, you will end up with many threads, waiting forever.

Comment: thx, Quite clear, but if I change the executorService to Executors.newCachedThreadPool(), the result is unpredictable.

Answer (score 0):

I would say your analysis is correct.

1. Yes, the first thread that aquires the lock holds it. The second thread blocks at the lock call.
2. Yes , the point of `ReentrantLock` is that the same thread can lock it multiple times. The lock guards not lines, but the locking call itself.

If you want that other threads have the ability to acquire the lock, then each `lock()` call must have a corresponding `unlock()` call.