# What is java's equivalnet of C#'s Monitor class?

Tags: java, c#, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

In C#, when I do

```
lock(this)
{
    //do something
}
```

it's shorthand for:

```
Monitor.Enter(this);
try
{
    //do something
}
finally
{
    Monitor.Exit(this);
}
```

What about java? Is

```
synchronized(this) {
    //do something
}
```

also short for something? Is there also some equivalent of the System.Threading.Monitor class in java?

Comment: You many not find exact match but see this excellent page. http://winterbe.com/posts/2015/04/30/java8-concurrency-tutorial-synchronized-locks-examples. Hope it will help

Comment: You might want to start with [Lock Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/newlocks.html)

Comment: It's basically the same thing; Java doesn't provide explicit access to an object's monitor.

Answer (score 2):

In Java there are:

- a `synchronized` block:

  ```
  synchronized(this) {
     //do something
  }
  ```
- a `synchronized` method:

  ```
  public synchronized void someMethod() {
     //do something
  }
  ```
- methods `wait()`, `notify()` and `notifyAll()` that every object has. They must be called when a thread has owned this object's monitor, in other words, from synchronized methods or blocks:

  ```
  public synchronized void waitForOtherTHreadToSetTheCondition() {
      while(!condition) {
          try {
              wait();
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
      }
  }

  public synchronized setCondition() {
      condition = true;
      notifyAll();
  }
  ```
- a [Lock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) interface and its subclasses:

  ```
      Lock l = ...;
      l.lock();
      try {
          // access the resource protected by this lock
      } finally {
          l.unlock();
      }
  ```
- many other helpful classes from the `java.util.concurrent` package, such as [Semaphore](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html), [SynchronousQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/SynchronousQueue.html), [CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html)

Answering your question "Is `synchronized` also shorthand for something?"

No. And there is no equivalent of `System.Threading.Monitor` in Java.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike .NET, Java's monitor locks are implemented with bytecode instructions rather than an API.  Where you would see a call to `Monitor.[Try]Enter` or `Monitor.Exit` in .NET IL, you would instead see a `monitorenter` or `monitorexit` instruction in Java bytecode (similarly guarded with try/finally).

The only way to utilize the built-in monitor lock programmatically is via the `synchronized` keyword or via `sun.misc.Unsafe`, which has `monitorEnter` and `monitorExit` methods.  However, `Unsafe` is an internal Oracle API that is not portable, and it is scheduled to be removed in future JDKs.  Using it is highly discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

You can find equivalent APIs in [Lock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) and [Object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html)

```
public void lock()
```

> Acquires the lock.

```
public void unlock()
```

> Attempts to release this lock.

Sample code:

```
 class X {
   ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
   // ...

   public void m() {
       assert !lock.isHeldByCurrentThread();
       lock.lock();
       try {
           // ... method body
       } finally {
           lock.unlock();
       }
   }
 }
```

Main different: You are calling `static` methods by passing the object to `Monitor` class. In Java, you have to execute the methods on instance ( `ReentrantLock` or `Object`) and hence passing of object is not required.

Mapping of `Monitor` in c# with `Lock` class in java

```
Enter(this)                =>    lock()
Exit(Object)               =>    unlock()
TryEnter(Object)           =>    tryLock()
TryEnter(Object, TimeSpan) =>    tryLock(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)
```

Mapping of `Monitor` in c# with `Object` class in java

```
Wait(Object)               =>     wait()
Pulse(object obj)          =>     notify()
PulseAll(Object)           =>     nofityAll()
```

Regarding other query:

```
synchronized(this) {
    //do something
}
```

is similar but not the same.

Related question : [Why use a ReentrantLock if one can use synchronized(this)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821801/why-use-a-reentrantlock-if-one-can-use-synchronizedthis/36827191#36827191)