# new Class vs new Object for the lock in java

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

Is there any difference between a lock created from a class and from an object?

```
class AWTInvocationLock {}
Object lock = new AWTInvocationLock();

public void foo(){
    synchronized (lock) {
        // ...
    }
}

public Object lock = new Object();
public void bar(){
    synchronized (lock) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

In `java.awt` I see this code and I'm wondering about the idea of `class AWTInvocationLock {}` instead of just `new Object()`

```
static void invokeAndWait(Object source, Runnable runnable)
    throws InterruptedException, InvocationTargetException
{
    // ...

    class AWTInvocationLock {}
    Object lock = new AWTInvocationLock();

    InvocationEvent event =
        new InvocationEvent(source, runnable, lock, true);

    synchronized (lock) {
        Toolkit.getEventQueue().postEvent(event);
        while (!event.isDispatched()) {
            lock.wait();
        }
    }

    //...
}
```

Comment: No, other than you probably should use neither. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821801/why-use-a-reentrantlock-if-one-can-use-synchronizedthis) for example

Comment: `Object` is of course also a class.

Comment: Synchronizing on a `new` object doesn’t do anything (unless a reference to it is published somehow).

Comment: I think the only reason somebody would use a local class that way is that if you're using a debugger the object's purpose is in its class name and `toString` result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to describe the code a bit:

```
class AWTInvocationLock {}
    Object lock = new AWTInvocationLock();

    InvocationEvent event =
        new InvocationEvent(source, runnable, lock, true);

    synchronized (lock) {
        Toolkit.getEventQueue().postEvent(event);
        while (!event.isDispatched()) {
            lock.wait();
        }
    }
```

The lock object reference is
escaping the local scope. A ref is stored in the `InvocationEvent` object:

```
InvocationEvent event =
            new InvocationEvent(source, runnable, lock, true);
```

The `EventQueue`'s dispatch thread is listening for posted Event objects. The thread invokes a `dispatch()` method on each event. I haven't looked
at the source code, but I guess that the `InvocationEvent.dispatch()` method pseudo-code looks like this;

```
 1. synchronize(lock)
 2. runnable.run() -- store any exceptions to a "throwable" reference variable
 3. lock.notify()
```

So the `EventQueue` dispatch thread calls `notify()` on the lock object, which releases the thread that calls `invokeAndWait()` from the `wait()` call in the next line.

> Is there any difference between a lock created from a class and from an object?

`AWTInvocationLock` is a named inner class with method scope. I've never actually seen one in the wild. Its a **really** obscure part of the
language, and one that almost no one I know is aware of. I would never use one because of that, and because Javadoc doesn't even recognize these and won't generate documentation for them!

Answer (score 0):

When a method that locks on a particular object is invoked, it locks on that *instance* of the object until the method invocation is complete. From that standpoint, it does not matter where you instantiate the object you need to lock on for *as long as it stays the same object during the method's invocation to achieve the locking results*.

Your first code segment creates a single object that is defined in the instance of the handler (the class that has method `foo()` on it). That means this handler will *not* single threaded because it will always lock on the *same* instance of the lock object you had created.

The AWT approach enhances this by creating another lock object which is independent of the handler instance. That means a single instance of the handler can process multiple events for different AWT components as long as each event is controlled by a dedicated lock object (`AWTInvocationLock()`).