# Illegal monitor state exception

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, asynchronous, concurrency

How to pass the polling thread to another thread for processing.
The program execution beings in a controller class which has a main method and a thread pool:

The main class Controller

```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    RunnableController controller = new RunnableController();

    System.out.println(incomingQueue.size());

    controller.initializeDb();
    controller.initialiseThreads();
    System.out.println("Polling");
    controller.initialUpdate(); 

}
```

The method which has the thread for Polling class

```
 private void initialiseThreads()
{       
    try {

        threadExecutorRead = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
PollingSynchronizer reader = new PollingSynchronizer(incomingQueue,dbConnection);   
        threadExecutorRead.submit(reader);

    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

The method which has the thread for the proccesor class

```
    private void initialUpdate()
{
    RunnableController.outgoingQueue = incomingQueue;
    if((RunnableController.outgoingQueue)!= null){
        try {
            threadExecutorFetch = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        MessageProcessor updater = new MessageProcessor(outgoingQueue, dbConnection);
            threadExecutorFetch.submit(updater);
            DBhandler dbhandler = new DBhandler();
            dbhandler.updateDb(getOutgoingQueue());

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

}
```

The Poller Class and the controller class

```
    public void run() {// Thread in the Poller class 
    int seqId = 0;
    while(true) {
        List<KpiMessage> list = null;
        try {
            list = fullPoll(seqId);
            if (!list.isEmpty()) {
                seqId = list.get(0).getSequence();
                incomingQueue.addAll(list);
                this.outgoingQueue = incomingQueue;             
                System.out.println("waiting");
                System.out.println("new incoming message");
                while(true){
                        wait(3000);
                        notify();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


          public void run() {// Second thread in the Processor Class
    synchronized (this){
        RunnableController.setOutgoingQueue(generate(outgoingQueue));
    }
    notify();
}   
 }
```

**My task and Question is :**

1.The controller should handle both the threads Poller & processor and it should only call the poller & processor thread

2.Now My question is how to make the poller thread wait for 3 seconds and paralelly notify the    processor.

**I get the error as follows:**

```
java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at PollingSynchronizer.run(PollingSynchronizer.java:76)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**How to achieve asynchronous processing here?**

Comment: what's line 76 in `PollingSynchronizer`? maybe you should add that class.

Comment: @Zhedar Its the Poller class which I have shown you as thread in poller class in run method...

Comment: Is the delay a one shot deal or do you need to do it once per processing loop in the poller?

Comment: @Perception the poller has to continuously run and delay every 3 seconds so that it also process the message at the waiting time.

Comment: @Babu - I don't see any reason, from your current code, that you cannot use `sleep` to simply pause the poller thread for ~ 3 seconds. If you absolutely need to synchronize the poller and processor though, I would recommend using a `CyclicBarrier`.

Comment: @Perception I actually need a Asynchronous message passing to run in that the Poller thread should keep on running, likewise the Processor thread should keep on updating and both these threads should be controlled by the controller.

Comment: @Babu - yea I get that part - you have a controller thats launching off your poller and processor (using executors). They are both running along asynchronously, but you want some kind of coordination/synchronization between them. Its the nature of that synchronization that you are trying to implement that is unclear. Is there some kind of *happens-before* requirement between the two components, or is it simply sufficient to pause every 3 seconds in the poller?

Comment: @Perception the process thread process the message and passes back to the controller which updates the database, so I pause the poller for this updation in database.

Comment: @Babu - ok, in this case you definitely want to use a synchronization aid between all three threads - `CyclicBarrier` would be my choice.

Comment: @Perception Thankyou I will try implementing using cyclic barrier and return to you...

Comment: @Perception May I know where to use Barriers in my class, because I referred the example, for my case I have two 3 classes one with main method and the other two with the run method... how to implement for my scenario....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886722/how-to-use-wait-and-notify-in-java) first. You cannot use `wait()` without holding the object's monitor. Also, from a short glance, it looks like you use a non-final static member in a multithreading context. Try to make that thread-safe.