# Is notifyAll() required at the end of a synchronized block?

Tags: java

I used to write a `synchronized` block like:

```
synchronized(foobar) {
    // do something
}
```

But, recently I saw someone write:

```
synchronized(foobar) {
    // do something
    foobar.notifyAll();
}
```

Is `foobar.notifyAll();` necessary? What happens if I omit it?

Comment: It is there to prevent deadlocks

Comment: AMR, the `synchronized` is there to prevent deadlocks, the `notifyAll()` is used to signal any other threads waiting on the monitor.

Comment: But isn't a dead lock when all threads are waiting and there is no notification?

Comment: It is as necessary as tying your shoelaces. If you wanna go running, you better do, but not really for a casual walk.

In other words, it's unnecessary unless it's necessary, and it's necessary when you want to make everyone wait for something to happen and then tell them they can do it because it happened.

Comment: `notify()` and `notifyAll()` are useful only when you called `wait()` somewhere.

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is that is depends on what you are doing.

If the goal of the synchronized block is simply to ensure that access / updates to a data structure are performed safely, then `notify()` or `notifyAll()` serves no purpose.

On the other hand, if the goal is to implement a "condition variable" then the `notify()` or `notifyAll()` calls work with a `wait` call like this ... for example:

```
private boolean flag;
private final Object mutex = new Object();

public void awaitFlag(boolean flag) {
    synchronized (mutex) {
        while (this.flag != flag) {
            mutex.wait();
        }
    }
}

public void setFlag(boolean flag) {
    synchronized (mutex) {
        this.flag = flag;
        mutex.notifyAll();
    }
}
```

The above implements a simple mechanism where threads call `awaitFlag()` to wait for the `flag` to become `true` or `false`.  When another thread calls `setFlag()` to change the flag, all of the threads that are currently waiting for the flag to change will get woken up by the `notifyAll()`.  This is an example where the `notifyAll()` is essential to the working of the code.

---

So to understand whether the `notify` or `notifyAll` code is necessary, you need to figure out if some other code *might* call `wait` on the same mutex / lock object.

Answer (score 4):

You don't *need* to do this. You only have to do it if the object (here `foobar`) is waiting to be notified. Notify only [Wakes up all threads that are waiting on this object's monitor.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html)

Answer (score 2):

In Java, you can use `wait()`, `notify()` and `notifyAll()` to achieve thread co-ordination. See [How to use wait and notify in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886722/how-to-use-wait-and-notify-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

The notifyAll() is to tell any other thread sleeping in a foobar.wait() that the current thread is about to release the lock and they can compete for the resource again.