# Don't know how use wait() and notify() in Java

Tags: java, android, wait, notify

I want to make something inside a thread that return what he did as string, and I'd like to wait for that string to do other thins. I've been reading about `wait()` and `notify()` but I dint get it. Can anyone help me?

**Here I create the thread that does the operations**

```
new Thread(

new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        synchronized(mensaje) {

            try {
                mensaje.wait();
                mensaje = getFilesFromUrl(value);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

}).start();
```

**And here where I wait for the string mensaje changes**

If the string is not "" then I show a button and some text

```
synchronized(mensaje) {

    if (mensaje.equals("")) {

        try {
            mensaje.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    btnOk.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    lblEstado.setText(mensaje);
}
```

**All this stuff is inside a method**

Comment: Take a look at the concurrency utils. Callable and Future are the main interfaces to know about there.

Comment: what's exactly your problem?

Comment: Ops, i forgot write the problem...

Comment: It's says object not locked by thread before notify (the notify() is after mensaje = getFilesFromUrl(value); but i forgot write it for this post...)

Answer (score 1):

`notify()`, `notifyAll()` and `wait()` basically work like this:

When you call `wait()` it releases the mutex that was taken by the synchronized block and puts the current thread to sleep in a queue.

`notify()` grabs one waiting thread from the front of the queue. That thread reacquires the mutex and continues running.

`notifyAll()` wakes up all threads in the queue.

To use this here is some pseudocode (lacks exception handling etc to be a bit more clear):

```
// in the thread that is supposed to wait
synchronized {
    while(!someCondition) {
        wait();
    }
    // At this point the other thread has made the condition true and notified you.
}


// In the other thread
synchronized {
    // Do something that changes someCondition to true.
    notifyAll();
}
```

Edit:
Or as Thilo wrote look at java.util.concurrent first. There might already be a ready-made solution for your use case. No need to use low-level constructs then.

Correction: There is a ready-made solution for your use-case:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html

and a corresponding Executor.

Comment: Ok, it seems very easy, but didn't work, just does not do anything. I just want to disable some buttons and enable them after the thread activity... but it's getting complicated!

Comment: One problem I see in your code is that both threads call wait(). Do both threads use notify()? Otherwise this leads to both threads blocking and waiting for a notify() that never comes.

Edit:
I just noticed your comment above. Did you call notify() from inside the synchronized block? It doesn't work if you don't hold the monitor when you call notify.

Comment: that was a mistake that dind't realized, but i can't enter the new code... i call wait() from main thread and notify() from the new thread...

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/886722/how-to-use-wait-and-notify-in-java