# Why do we need to synchronize on the same object for notify() to work

Tags: java, synchronization, wait, notify

I was getting `java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException`. I referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886722/how-to-use-wait-and-notify-in-java) question and it solved my problem. The first answer is

```
To be able to call notify() you need to synchronize on the same object.

synchronized (someObject) {
    someObject.wait();
}

/* different thread / object */
synchronized (someObject) {
    someObject.notify();
}
```

**My question is why we need to synchronize on the same object ad how it works?**

As far as my understanding goes when we say

```
synchronized (someObject) {
    someObject.wait();
}
```

we get a lock on object someObject and then we call wait() on it. **Now how can another thread get lock on same object to call notify() on it?** What am I missing?

Comment: **why you are mentioning the your question in bold ? (like this)**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Why does `notify` need a lock too?**

Imagine this scenario:

```
synchronized(x){
        while(x.count < 4) {
          x.wait();
          //...
        }
}
```

Imagine now a `notify` elsewhere  without any lock around it:

```
//...
println(x.count); // print 3
x.count++;
if(count == 4) 
  x.notify()
//...
```

At first glance, the whole sounds to always work as expected.
However, imagine this race condition:

```
//Thread1 enters here
synchronized(x){
     while(x.count < 4) {
         //condition is judged true and thread1 is about to wait 
         //..but..ohh!! Thread2 is prioritized just now !
         //Thread2, acting on notify block side, notices that with its current count incrementation, 
         //count increases to 4 and therefore a notify is sent.... 
         //but...but x is expected to wait now !!! for nothing maybe indefinitely !
       x.wait();
       //maybe block here indefinitely waiting for a notify that already occurred!
     }
}
```

If only we had a way to tell this to `notify` side:

Thread 1:  "Humm..`notify`, you are cute but I've just started to evaluate my condition (`x.count < 4`) to true, so please... don't be silly by sending your expected notification just now (before I put my status to waiting), otherwise, I would be ridiculous to wait for a thing that already passed"

Thread2: "Ok ok... I will put a lock around my logic in order to stay consistent, so that I send my notification **after** your wait call releases our shared lock, and thus you will receive this notif, allowing to quit your waiting status ;)"

Thus, always place a lock on the `notify` side, on the same object that is hold by wait, in order to avoid this situation and let the relationship always consistent.

**=> A logic leading to a `notify` and a logic leading to a `wait` should never overlap.**

Comment: @Mik378 great explaination very easy to understand.Thank you

Comment: I don't think it's neccessary to hold the lock. In your example, the condition variable (x) should be modified  after synchornized, that's all you need. I think you can release the lock(monitor) after changing the condition variable(x), and then notify. Actually in c++, it even encourages to release the lock before notifying. see [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/notify_all)

Answer (score 5):

As per the javadoc for [Object#wait()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29)

> The **current thread must own this object's monitor**. The thread releases
>   ownership of this monitor and waits until another thread notifies
>   threads waiting on this object's monitor to wake up either through a
>   call to the notify method or the notifyAll method. The thread then
>   waits until it can re-obtain ownership of the monitor and resumes
>   execution.

To use wait/notify the thread must have the lock, otherwise
[IllegalMonitorStateException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalMonitorStateException.html) is thrown

> Throws: **IllegalMonitorStateException** - if the current thread is not
>   the owner of the object's monitor.

### Why

So,
 `wait()` makes current thread *release* the lock

`notify()` signals other waiting thread(s) which then *try to acquire* the lock.

For doing either, the current thread **must** have the lock. And it makes sense!

### *Edit*

- Why must thread calling wait() hold the lock is pretty obvious now.
- But why must thread calling notify() hold the lock? Well, for one, to prove its `authenticity`. Otherwise any thread could keep firing `false notifications` and the `waiting` threads would keep getting interrupted. *Thankfully that is not the case.*

Comment: But why is it necessary to hold the lock to call notify? Saying "because the spec says so" is true but doesn't really answert the question.

Comment: You write "current thread must have the lock": why does it have to have the lock to signal other threads? They don't care who is holding the lock; they will attempt to acquire it anyway.

Comment: `How can you release a resource which you don't have in the first place?` WOuld that help?

Comment: That's why you must hold the lock to call wait. But we're discussing notify.

Answer (score 1):

**wait/notify are typically used to wait for some other thread to accomplish a task, or to wait until a certain condition is satisfied.**

Lets say we have an object called *objectA* and two threads called *thread1 and thread2*.
*thread1* has some thread safe task,so it acquires objectA's monitor using *synchronized* block.

```
       synchronized (objectA) {
          //here thread1  owns objectA's monitor
       }
```

In java calling wait() means releasing monitors so that other threads can get this monitor and achieve its tasks and current thread goes into some state called *waiting state* for objectA's monitor.

```
     synchronized(objectA){
        //here thread1 owns objectA's monitor.
        objectA.wait();
        //here thred1 releases monitor of objectA's monitor and goes into waiting state and waits to get objectA's monitor once again to complete its task.
     }
```

Now thread2 can own the objectA's monitor and excutes its task.

```
    synchronized(objectA){
        //here thread2 owns objectA's monitor.
        //some task;
     }
```

Once task completes it notifies the other threads in waiting state that it is released the monitor on the object it owns. **please note that to call *notify()* also thread should be owner of object monitor**.

```
       synchronized(objectA){
        //here thread2 owns objectA's monitor.
        //some task;
        objectA.notify();
       //it signals some other thread that it can wake up from wait,so that other waiting threads can owns objectA's monitor
     }
```

here calling wait() on objectA and calling notify() on other object(lets say objectB) is makes no use to *thread1*.Since *thread1* waiting to get monitor on *objectA* not on other object(lets say objectB).

**update**
`Why obtain monitor to call notify()`
to call *notify()* we need to obtain monitor,because it is guaranteed that two threads trying to call notify( ) on one object won’t step on each other’s toes(to aviod race condition).
[why we need to get lock before notify](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/05/wait-notify-and-notifyall-in-java.html)

Comment: Good explanation but question still remains why obtain lock/monitor to notify()?

Comment: Calling `notify` does not release the monitor; it signals some other thread that it can wake up from `wait` and try to obtain the monitor. Also, as you can see from the diagram you link to, `notify` makes the thread enter the *runnable* state, not *terminated* state.

Comment: @Joni Thank you very much for correcting me.I am sorry I misunderstand the concept.I think I updated it correctly now.please look into it any correct me if any mistake exists

Comment: @Joni So after calling notify() inside synchronized block, will it release the monitor that the thread acquires while entering the sync block?

Comment: Never mind got the answer **Wait immediately looses the lock, whereas Notify will leave the lock only when the ending bracket is encountered**.

Comment: @Prabhaker I doubt it is because of synchronization that we need to get lock before notify() coz sync always has been programmers design choice. Why make it a restriction?

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the Hotspot JVM source code I found this: The `notify()` method modifies the wait set of the object's monitor. (The wait set of an object is the set of threads that have called `wait()` on it.) If the access to the wait set was not synchronized bad things could happen: for example a thread could be dropped from the set without ever being awoken. Requiring that the calling thread owns the monitor before calling `notify()` solves this issue, though other solutions could also exist.

There are also other arguments, such as notify being called without holding the monitor often implying a programmer error, but I don't think that's enough to motivate such a restriction.