# One thread updates variable and another read it, do I need something special

Tags: java, android

I have a class that has the object "Card". This class keeps checking to see if the object is not null anymore. Only one other thread can update this object. Should I just do it like the code below? Use volatile?Syncronized? lock (which I dont know how to use really)? What do you recommend as easiest solution?

```
Class A{

 public Card myCard = null;


 public void keepCheck(){

    while(myCard == null){
       Thread.sleep(100)
    }
    //value updated
     callAnotherMethod();
 }
```

Another thread has following:

```
public void run(){
     a.myCard = new Card(5);
 }
```

What do you suggest?

Comment: You should use a proper wait event (see the [Guarded Block](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html) tutorial), otherwise you run the risk of the "watching" thread seeing the reference before it sees completely initialized member fields of the `Card`.

Comment: Of course that problem can be completely avoided if the creating thread creates the reference *then* assigns myCard to equal that reference.

Comment: @GabeSechan The JLS only makes that guarantee for `final` fields of the object (even in the case where you're creating then assigning). The *only* way you can guarantee that another thread sees the up-to-date state of the object is to use `synchronized`, which has happens-before guarantees about actions that take place up to that point. The issue is not with one thread getting access to the reference before the constructor returns - that's impossible of course; the issue relates to execution/visibility reordering and also low level caching of out-of-date data (esp. on multicore systems).

Comment: @JasonC A reference is basically a double pointer (doubled so it can be moved in memory).  Assignment of the variable is atomic-  all fields update at once because all you're doing is updating a single pointer in memory.  It works just fine.  Now if the thread that's using it wants to do more than a null check it will need to use more sophisticated locking like wait or a semaphore.

Comment: @JasonC Worries about multicore caching are invalid in this specific case where one thread is waiting for the variable to be non-null-  if it reads an out of date version it will simply get it the next time it checks.  This is a very frequent pattern in rendering code-  one thread renders an object to a bitmap, and the drawing thread will copy the current value of the reference to the bitmap and use it to draw to the screen.  This allows lockless drawing.

Comment: @GabeSechan *"Now if the thread that's using it wants to do more than a null check"* I've assumed that `callAnotherMethod()` will be using the data; that may not be a correct assumption.

Comment: interesting discussion. I have got alot to learn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a proper wait event (see the [Guarded Block](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html) tutorial), otherwise you run the risk of the "watching" thread seeing the reference before it sees completely initialized member fields of the `Card`. Also `wait()` will allow the thread to sleep instead of sucking up CPU in a tight while loop.

For example:

```
Class A {

    private final Object cardMonitor = new Object();
    private volatile Card myCard;

    public void keepCheck () {
        synchronized (cardMonitor) {
            while (myCard == null) {
                try {
                    cardMonitor.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException x) {
                    // either abort or ignore, your choice
                }
            }
        }
        callAnotherMethod();
    }

    public void run () {
        synchronized (cardMonitor) {
            myCard = new Card(5);
            cardMonitor.notifyAll();
        }
    }

}
```

I made `myCard` private in the above example. I do recommend avoiding lots of public fields in a case like this, as the code could end up getting messy fast.

Also note that you do not *need* `cardMonitor` -- you could use the `A` itself, but having a separate monitor object lets you have finer control over synchronization.

Beware, with the above implementation, if `run()` is called while `callAnotherMethod()` is executing, it will change `myCard` which may break `callAnotherMethod()` (which you do not show). Moving `callAnotherMethod()` inside the synchronized block is one possible solution, but you have to decide what the appropriate strategy is there given your requirements.

Comment: by the way, why do you have while(card ==null) when you have the wait! should'nt it just be "if" since you wait for the wakeup once

Comment: @Snake quick comment from phone - two things: 1. If run notifies before keepcheck waits, keepcheck will miss notification. So we check condition first (in this case, condition==true implies notify was already called). 2. Threads can wake up spuriously (or via interrupt()) even if condition isn't true. Google "spurious wakeups".

Answer (score 0):

The variable needs to be volatile when modifying from a different thread if you intend to poll for it, but a better solution is to use `wait()`/`notify()` or even a `Semaphore` to keep your other thread sleeping until `myCard` variable is initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a classic producer/consumer case.

You can handle this case using wait()/notify() methods. See here for an example: [How to use wait and notify in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886722/how-to-use-wait-and-notify-in-java)

Or here, for more examples: http://www.programcreek.com/2009/02/notify-and-wait-example/