# IllegalMonitorStateException calling wait() and notify()

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, wait, notify

I've read the example of producer and consumer, and I changed a little. Pro() will print "first", and con() will print "second". I want every "second" appears after "first".

```
public class test {
    test() { }

    synchronized void pro() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    System.out.println("First!");
                    notify();
                    try {
                        wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }       
        }).start();
    }

    synchronized void con() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    System.out.println("Second!");              
                    notify();                   
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test m = new test();
        m.pro();
        m.con();
    }
}
```

The errors that occur are:

```
First!
Exception in thread "Thread-0" Exception in thread "Thread-1"
java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.lang.Object.notify(Native Method)
    at test$1.run(test.java:12)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at test$2.run(test.java:32)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/886722/how-to-use-wait-and-notify-in-java

Comment: @Java42 Thank you. I know there should be "synchronized" and I've already added "synchronized" key words to my methods. Why is it still wrong?

Comment: Update your question and don't say "It does't work" but rather say something like "I am getting error:" <add error msg or stack trace here>.

Comment: @Sentimental your `run()` methods should be syncrhonized rather than the methods `pro()` and `con()`.

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple problems occurring simultaneously here.

The first is the obvious `IllegalMonitorStateException`. This exception occurs when `wait` or `notify` is called on an object when the calling thread doesn't hold that object's monitor lock. Even though the calls syntactically occur within a `synchronized` method, the actual calls to `wait` and `notify` occur on different threads and operate on different objects.

What's happening is that your `pro` and `con` methods are synchronized on your instance. Since they're called from the `main` method, the main thread is the one that takes the monitor locks. But these methods simply start other threads and then release the locks.

The  `wait` and `notify` calls are implicitly `this.wait` and `this.notify` and they are within `Runnable` anonymous inner classes, so in these cases the `this` refers to the `Runnable` instances, not the outer `test` instance that's been synchronized. The rule is that the same thread that calls `wait` (or `notify`) on an object must also hold the monitor lock on the object. Since that's not the case, `IllegalMonitorStateException` is thrown. An additional problem is that the `wait` and `notify` calls are on **different** `Runnable` instances. Different threads must use wait/notify on the **same** object in order to communicate.

What you need to do is rearrange the code so that the `synchronized` blocks occur in the threads that do the actual synchronization. Then, you want to make sure that the `synchronized`, `wait`, and `notify` operations are all on the same object. Perhaps the best way to do that is to store your `test` instance in a static field (say, make `m` be a static field instead of a local variable). The `run` methods are members of the `Runnable` instances, so you can't just make these methods synchronized. Instead, you have to use `synchronized` blocks and pass the instance on which you want to synchronize. You can also remove the `synchronized` keywords from the `pro` and `con` methods since these methods don't actually need synchronization. The resulting code will look something like this:

```
static test m = new test();

void pro() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (m) {
                ...
                m.notify();
                ...
                m.wait();
                ...
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

You'll have to do something similar to the `con` method.

Now, the code should run without throwing `IllegalMonitorStateException`. But this uncovers a second problem: it might not work. It might deadlock because of the *lost wakeup problem*. A full explanation is beyond the scope of this answer. Briefly though, if the thread started by `pro` runs first, it might call `notify` when no thread is waiting. If this occurs, nothing happens. Then that thread continues and calls `wait`. Next, the `con` thread might start, and the first thing it does is call `wait`. Now both threads are blocked in `wait` and a `notify` will never occur.

The way to solve this is to have waiting and notification **based on the state of the object**. It won't work to call `wait` without checking the state of the object, nor will it work to call `notify` without changing the object's state.

For a full explanation of how to use `wait` and `notify` properly, see Goetz, *Java Concurrency in Practice*, chapter 14.

Comment: Hello Stuart, I stll have a question about synchronization in Swing timer. Whould you please help?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003532/swing-timer-synchronization

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able (without `IllegalMonitorStateException`) to call `wait()` and `notify()` methods of some object, thread has to acquire object monitor first. That means this methods should be called either in `synchronized` block by the same object you `wait()` for, or in `synchronized` method, where you will be able to call `this.wait()`.

Now let's take a look at your code:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Second!");              
        notify();                   
    }
}
```

You `wait()` and `notify()` for anonymous `Runnable` instance. This is probably a bug caused by misunderstanding of wait/notify mechanics. Try reading [this article](http://www.programcreek.com/2009/02/notify-and-wait-example/) for further information.