# Object not locked by thread before notify() in onPostExecute

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I try to notify adapters of listviews of main class in onPostExecute but I receive the error: java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException:object not locked by thread before notify()

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    popularfragment.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    recentfragment.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: are you sure this exception is caused by this code?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

The `.notify()` method has to be called from within a `synchronized` context, ie from inside a `synchronized` block.

The [`java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalMonitorStateException.html) is thrown when you call `.notify()` on an object that is not used as the lock for the synchronized block in which you call notify. For example, the following works;

```
synchronized(obj){
    obj.notify();
}
```

But this will throw the exception;

```
synchronized(obj){
    // notify() is being called here when the thread and 
    // synchronized block does not own the lock on the object.
    anotherObj.notify();        
}
```

Reference;

- [IllegalMonitorStateException API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalMonitorStateException.html)
- [How to use wait & notify](https://stackoverflow.com/a/886799/2182928)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error, but (for me) the answer suggested by Rudi Kershaw wasn't the issue... I called the `notify()` of a Notification the wrong way (see the *last line* of both snippets):

**Not working:**

```
public void update() {
    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setPriority(AesPrefs.getInt(R.string.PRIORITY_NOTIFICATION_BATTERY, NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX))
            .setOngoing(true);
    mBuilder.setWhen(AesPrefs.getLong(Loader.gStr(R.string.LAST_FIRED_BATTERY_NOTIFICATION) + Const.START_CLIPBOARD_NOTIFICATION_DELAYED, -1));
    mManager.notify(); // <- lil' mistake
}
```

**Working:**

```
public void update() {
    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setPriority(AesPrefs.getInt(R.string.PRIORITY_NOTIFICATION_BATTERY, NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX))
            .setOngoing(true);
    mBuilder.setWhen(AesPrefs.getLong(Loader.gStr(R.string.LAST_FIRED_BATTERY_NOTIFICATION) + Const.START_CLIPBOARD_NOTIFICATION_DELAYED, -1));
    mManager.notify(Const.NOTIFICATION_CLIPBOARD, mBuilder.build()); // <- ok ;-)
}
```

Comment: hey i used your code but i don't know where Const has been declared plz tell me

Comment: Const contains constant values in my project. Press Ctrl+P (set the cursor on "notifiy" and press the shortcut) to see the parameter info -> its an Integer (something like an ID you have to give the notification).
You can also add a new Class called "Const", simply press Alt+Enter when the cursor is on Const and select create "new class". ;) Got it?
*NOTE:* if you have multiple notifications, they need to have different IDs. To clear the notification you will use this ID as well.