# Static Adapter cuses object not locked by thread before notify() in notifyAll() even after usign Synchronized

Tags: android, multithreading, adapter, android-recyclerview

so I'm using a static adapter to notify the Recycler view from outside my fragment.
and when I call `notifyAll()` it throws: `object not locked by thread before notify() in notifyAll()`

I've tried the solution linked here: 
[Object not locked by thread before notify() in onPostExecute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24185921/object-not-locked-by-thread-before-notify-in-onpostexecute)

but using:

```
synchronized(adapter){
    // notify() is being called here when the thread and 
    // synchronized block does not own the lock on the object.
    adapter.notifyAll();        
}
```

did not fix my problem! then I've used this:

```
    synchronized(adapter){
        // notify() is being called here when the thread and 
        // synchronized block does not own the lock on the object.
        adapter.wait()
        adapter.notifyAll();        
    }
```

**it causes that the app Freezed with no responding at all!**
any suggestions, please??

Comment: Are you confusing `Object.notifyAll()` with `Adapter.notifyDataSetChange()`? Are using doing multithreading at all?

Comment: Hi Daniel! I'm not using the multithreading but I got the error above for some reason.
"Adapter.notifyDataSetChange()" is not working in my situation since there is no changes in the data, the change only with a drawable.
when I use an "adapter.notifyAll()" it works for the first time, then crashes as I mentioned above