# Where is notifyAll getting called at the end of Thread.join()

Tags: java, multithreading

From jdk 1.7.0_45
The instance method of Thread.join(long miilliseconds) works by making the caller Thread wait on this Thread's Object monitor.Also,the javadoc explicitly states that

***`As a thread terminates the this.notifyAll method is invoked. It is recommended that applications not use wait, notify, or notifyAll on Thread instances.`***

```
  public final synchronized void join(long millis)
    throws InterruptedException {
        long base = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long now = 0;

        if (millis < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("timeout value is negative");
        }

        if (millis == 0) {
            while (isAlive()) {
                wait(0);
            }
        } else {
            while (isAlive()) {
                long delay = millis - now;
                if (delay <= 0) {
                    break;
                }
                wai t(delay);
                now = System.currentTimeMillis() - base;
            }
        }
    }
```

**I don't see notifyAll() getting called so that the Thread calling join() gets the monitor for this Thread's Object**

If I am calling `t.join(0)` on thread t,then I am not implementing `notifyAll()` in my run() code.So how does the caller thread(the thread which calls t.join() gets notified)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join-long-) says (my emphasis):

> Waits at most millis milliseconds for this thread to die. A timeout of 0 means to wait forever.
>
> This implementation uses a loop of this.wait calls conditioned on this.isAlive. **As a thread terminates the this.notifyAll method is invoked.** It is recommended that applications not use wait, notify, or notifyAll on Thread instances.

The join method is not responsible for the notification, it's the thing doing the waiting.

The notifying would be done by whatever JVM code is responsible for terminating the thread.

Comment: I am not implementing notifyAll in the run() code of the joined thread t.Check my edit now

Comment: @Kumar: i think my answer is the same, when the thread dies the jvm fires off its notification. it's in the jdk implementation, in native code.

Comment: so you are telling me that all threads after dying relinquish any Objects that they may have synchronized upon?

Comment: @Kumar: not sure i follow. the thread is the thing being synced on. the thread reaches the end of the run method it's executing, the JVM acquires the thread's lock and does a notifyAll, then it would release the lock and the thread gets sent to GC.

Comment: I doubt "Thread gets sent to GC"..As I am having the reference of Thread Object from the main program

Comment: @Kumar: you're right, GC would wait til you cut it loose

Comment: @KumarAbhinav your run() method is _not_ the base of the thread's call stack.  your run() method is called by a library routine that does the notifyAll() after your run() method returns.

Comment: @jameslarge if you post this as an answer with some link,I will accept it

Answer (score 1):

You must first understand the [notify-wait mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886722/how-to-use-wait-and-notify-in-java). One thread waits (on an object) until another notifies it.

Example code

```
// in main thread
Thread t1 = new Thread(..);
t1.start();
t1.join();
```

The implementation of `Thread#start()` is `native`. The implementation is required to invoke `notifyAll()` once the `Thread#run()` method completes whether abruptly or normally.

This is required so that the thread calling `join()` can be notified.

In the example above, when the `main` thread calls `join()`, it eventually executes

```
wait(delay);
```

which is invoked on the `Thread` instance referenced by `t1`. This will cause the `main` thread to block until `notify` or `notifyAll` is invoked on the same `Thread` object which is what the `native` implementation of `start` must do, ie. invoke `this.notifyAll()` (probably implemented in `native` code).

This is also the reason why developers absolutely should not call `wait` and `notify` on `Thread` instances, so as not to mess with this `join` implementation.

Comment: You said "native implementation of start must do, ie. invoke this.notifyAll()".i think notifyall should we called after joined thread's run() has completed and run will execute only when start has completed.so where will notifyall() get called from?

Comment: @KumarAbhinav `start` internally calls `run()`. When `run()` completes, `start` (presumably) calls `notifyAll()`.