# multithreading in java,difficulty in wait

Tags: java, multithreading

This is the part of my code,I am facing problems in using `wait()`

```
class Leader extends Thread {
    private Table table;
    synchronized public void run()
    {
        while(true)
        { 
            try
            {
                while(table.getResources()!=0)
                    wait();

                table.putResources(5); // here I am updating the value(I have a table class)
            } catch(InterruptedException e) { }
        }
    }
}


class Soldier extends Thread {

    public void run() 
    {
        while(true) 
        {
            try 
            {
                synchronized(this) 
                {

                    if(table.getResources()==this.need_Value)    //checking value of resource 
                    {
                        sleep(1000);
                        table.clearResources();      //this will put the value of resource to 0
                        notifyAll();
                    }
                }
            } catch(InterruptedException e) { }
        }
    }
}
```

So basically I have a thread of leader class and a thread of Leader class. Initially resources is `0` so in the Soldier class resources is updated to `5`. Suppose now for `Soldier` class need_Value was `5`,so it will update value of resources to `0`. So now `Leader` class should again run as resources is `0`,but actually it is still waiting. So is there anything wrong with my `wait()`?

PS- Assume I have Table class and all the constructors and variables used. I have omitted them because the code was too long

Comment: There is no `notify()` in your code. `wait()` will sleep until someone calls `notify()` or `notifyAll()` on the same object.

Comment: I have tried using notify() after clearing resources in soldier class but still it was waiting.I have editted the code with notify()

Comment: You must notify the leader.

Comment: You need to synchronize, `wait()` and `notify()` on the same object in both threads. In your case probably on `table` object.

Comment: @Markus Malkusch I tried that but that also didnt help.Basically I want to resume Leader thread after clearResources of Soldier thread has run.

Comment: @Banthar On using wait and notify on table object,I am getting this error 
    `Exception in thread "Leader Thread" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
 at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Object.wait(Unknown Source)
 at Leader.run(Leader.java:22)`

Comment: @Noober You need to use the `synchronize` keyword around a common object...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You `notify` on another object than you `wait`.

Your `Leader` class synchronizes on `this` (implicitly because you put synchronized on the instance method). So your `Leader` waits on the `Leader` instance to be notified.

In your `Soldier` class you also synchronize on `this` and you notify on that `Soldier` instance.

But since you notify on the `Soldier` instance and the `Leader` waits on the `Leader` instance it will not get notified.

Both instances `Soldier` and `Leader` should use the same synchronization object.

You might want to fix this by using the `Leader` instance as synchronization object in the `Soldier`

```
class Soldier extends Thread {

    private Leader leader;

    public Soldier(Leader leader) {
        this.leader = leader;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            try
            {
                synchronized(leader)
                {

                    if(table.getResources()==this.need_Value)    //checking value of resource
                    {
                        sleep(1000);
                        table.clearResources();      //this will put the value of resource to 0
                        leader. notifyAll();
                    }
                }
            } catch(InterruptedException e) { }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have another doubt this was my main code-
      `Table table=new Table(0);
  Thread leader=new Leader("Leader",table);
  Thread ST1=new Soldier("Soldier",table,4)
                leader.start();ST1.start();
`
So I think both the threads were called on table object.So my code should have worked as the calling instance of both threads were the same i.e table

Comment: @Noober Both threads are created with the `Table` object, but they don't synchronize on it. If you want the table object to be the synchronization object you must use it explicitely in `Leader` and `Soldier`, e.g. `synchronized (table) {  }`. This would also work.

Comment: Yes I tried using `synchronized(table)` and it worked,but my question is when I use `synchronized(this)` ,here `this` is the calling object which is `table` so these two statements should be equivalent or not??

Comment: @Noober No, `this` refers to the current object, not the caller. That's why you are able to do something like `this.interrupt()` in your `Leader` class, because I guess `Table` doesn't have a method `interrupt()` ;)

Comment: Yes I dont have any `interrupt()` method in `Table`.I know `this` is the current object but are `this` and `Table` not same in this case??
Sorry,I am just a beginner and I am really grateful to you for helping me out.

Comment: `this` only refers to `Table` in the `Table` object. What you do is passing a reference of `Table` to the `Leader` and `Soldier`. Nevertheless the `this` reference inside `Leader` refers to the current `Leader` instance and not to the `Table`. Take a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html

Answer (score 0):

Read the answer in this question: [How to use wait and notify in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886722/how-to-use-wait-and-notify-in-java) It explains in detail how to properly use the Wait() and Notify() functions.

Comment: If a question is a duplicate flag it as such rather than posting an answer. That way everything gets nicely linked together