# Why does Java suspend the main thread when it reaches an infinite loop?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

My code has a UI thread that updates a Boolean variable. The problem I'm having is I want the main program to continuing executing when the variable becomes true.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
//Display the UI by creating an instance of Node
Node node = new Node();

//Wait for the node to connect to a router before continuing
while(!isConnectedToRouter);

//Do other things
}
```

While debugging I noticed the main thread suspends itself so main never gets to "Do other things". Even after another thread makes the boolean isConnectedToRouter true. If i change the while loop to

```
//Wait for the node to connect to a router before continuing
while(!isConnectedToRouter){
    Thread.sleep(1);
}
```

It works, but It makes me aware that I'm doing something wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is `isConnectedToRouter` declared as `volatile`?

Comment: No, it's "private static boolean"

Comment: It *should* be `volatile`, otherwise changing the value in another thread is never guaranteed to become visible in the main thread. Anyway, busy looping is rarely a good idea. It's better wait until the other thread is ready, and let it wake up the main thread when done.

Comment: Thanks guys, making the Boolean volatile made it work. I guess the main thread cached its value. I've never used volatile before but it makes sense now. As for the other advice I can see why busy waiting is bad design but it's what I have to work with now. I'll keep that in mind though. Thank you.

Comment: Avoiding the busy wait is not very difficult: you could use the low level primitives from Object [wait/notify/notifyAll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/886722/how-to-use-wait-and-notify-in-java) or use the higher level interfaces from `java.util.concurrent`.

Comment: @kiheru You should flesh that out into an answer.  It's the right answer.

Comment: This thread is not suspended. It is running, and producing smoke from the CPU.

Answer (score 2):

Better than busy waiting is sleeping in the main thread until it's time to continue.

[java.util.concurrent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) has high level level interfaces for threading that are easier to use safely and fit most situations.

Waiting using [CountDownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) for example could be done like:

```
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
```

, this object should be visible in both the main thread and in your worker. Locking needs to be made using the *same* object.

Waiting in the main thread:

```
latch.await();
```

And when the other thread is ready:

```
latch.countDown();
```

This implementation has the advantage that you don't need to worry about the case where the worker thread is ready *before* the waiting phase is started. In that situation the `await()` does the right thing and returns immediately.

In this situation the old low level methods from `Object` could also be used, but special care would be needed to handle the case where the worker thread is ready before the main thread would wait - without checking that it would be easy to lock up the main thread. So I recommend to sticking `java.util.concurrent`, unless you have good reasons to not to. Those classes exist to help writing safe threading code.

*note: I left out the code handling `InterruptedExceptions` for brevity - that should be done both with `latch.wait()` and `Object.wait()`*

Answer (score 0):

YOU should make the boolean volatle in order that the main thread can read the latest value of that boolean variable, rather than just reading the values in registers.