# When and How to use wait() and notify()

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, runnable, notify

I found this example from SO. Now, I was trying to understand the usage of `wait()` and `notify()/notifyAll()`. In which scenario and why do we need this.

```
class BlockingQueue<T> {

    private Queue<T> queue = new LinkedList<T>();
    private int capacity;

    public BlockingQueue(int capacity) {
        this.capacity = capacity;
    }

    public synchronized void put(T element) throws InterruptedException {
        while (queue.size() == capacity) {
             System.out.println("Waiting...");
            wait();

        }

        queue.add(element);
        notify(); // notifyAll() for multiple producer/consumer threads
    }

    public synchronized T take() throws InterruptedException {
        while (queue.isEmpty()) {
            wait();
        }

        T item = queue.remove();
        notify(); // notifyAll() for multiple producer/consumer threads
        return item;
    }
}
```

So, implemented `Runnable` and overriden `run()` method like below

```
 @Override
    public void run() {
        // synchronized (this) {
        BlockingQueue<Integer> s = new BlockingQueue(10);
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            try {
                s.put(i);
                if (i > 9) {
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "  : " + s.take());
                }
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " ExtendsThread : Counter : " + i);
            } //}
            //notify();
            catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ExtendsThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        }

    }
```

And, running the thread like below

```
 ImplementsRunnable rc = new ImplementsRunnable();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(rc, "A");
        t1.start();
```

When I'm running it, then it is stuck after `counter : 9` and keep on waiting for forever. Anyone suggest me what's wrong here ?

Comment: _what's wrong with my implementation for understanding wait() and notify()_ What is your understanding of those methods? What do you think they do?

Comment: Maybe [this SQ question and the accepted answer][1] helps you [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/886722/how-to-use-wait-and-notify-in-java

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis `wait()` will wait and `notify()` will notify waiting threads. Am I correct ?

Comment: Create a new `Runnable` which puts values into a `BlockingQueue` and a `Runnable` which takes the values from a `BlockingQueue`, pass both the same instance of `BlockQueue`, start them and let them run...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Let me try this one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your concept is slightly flawed.  The `BlockingQueue` can act as bridge in a producer/consumer pattern.

That is, it allows one thread to write content to it and another thread to read content from it, but it's doing it in such away that if:

- There are no items to be taken, it waits until new items arrive
- If there are too many items, it waits for items to be removed

In this case, the `wait` and `notify` are internal messaging for the instance of the `BlockingQueue`

You can have a look at [Intrinsic Locks and Synchronization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html).

So, instead of using just one thread, you should be using (at least) two, a produce and a consumer...

## Producer

This takes an instance of `BlockingQueue` and adds `int` values to it.  Each time it stops for 1 second before adding the next

```
public class Producer implements Runnable {

    private BlockingQueue<Integer> queue;

    public Producer(BlockingQueue<Integer> queue) {
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Put " + index);
                queue.put(index);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            }
        }
    }

}
```

## Consumer

The consumer takes a `BlockQueue` and reads `int` values from it, which be blocked until a value exists.

```
public class Consumer implements Runnable {

    private BlockingQueue<Integer> queue;

    public Consumer(BlockingQueue<Integer> queue) {
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                Integer value = queue.take();
                System.out.println("Took " + value);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication220.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

You can get these start using something like...

```
BlockingQueue bq = new BlockingQueue(10);
Thread p = new Thread(new Producer(bq));
Thread c = new Thread(new Consumer(bq));
c.setDaemon(true);
c.start();
p.start();
```

You should note that there is a small delay between the `put` messages, but almost no delay between the `took` messages.  This is the queue in action.  The `Consumer` is blocking/waiting on the queue to have something to give it.

You can play around with the `Producer` and `Consumer`, maybe changing their times (having a longer delay in the `Consumer` before taking an item for example) to see how this might cause different effects

> When I'm running it, then it is stuck after counter : 9 and keep on waiting for forever

This is likely because you've exceeded the capacity of the queue and it's `put` method is blocking until you take something from it (you essentially have a dead lock, where the queue is waiting for you to take something from it, but you can't because you're locked on the `put`)

Things to remember:

- For two or more threads to work with monitor locks, they MUST share the same instance of the monitor/object lock.  In this case, the same instance of `BlockingQueue`
- `notify` will wake one object whose is waiting on the same instance of the monitor lock's `wait` method.  There is no way to know which one.  This can be useful if you have multiple consumers, but don't care about the order in which the data is processed, for example

**Updated with additional example**

So, this takes the `Thread.sleep` out of the `Producer` (and allows the producer to produce 100 values) and adds a `Thread.sleep` to the `Consumer`.

This way, the `Producer` will reach it's capacity before the `Consumer` can drain it, forcing it to wait until the `Consumer` can take values from it...

```
public class Producer implements Runnable {

    private BlockingQueue<Integer> queue;

    public Producer(BlockingQueue<Integer> queue) {
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int index = 0; index < 100; index++) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Put " + index);
                queue.put(index);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            }
        }
    }

}

public class Consumer implements Runnable {

    private BlockingQueue<Integer> queue;

    public Consumer(BlockingQueue<Integer> queue) {
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                Integer value = queue.take();
                System.out.println("Took " + value);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: why is it adding and removing at same time ? Please correct my understanding. I was expecting to work this code like, it should keep on adding elements till it reaches the limit and once it reached then it should wait and then it should remove one elements and add one elements. That's the way I was expecting to work `wait` and `notify`.

Comment: `wait` and `notify` work through different threads, if you tried this on the same thread, you'd end up with the problem you have, where it blocks indefinitely.  Try this, put a `Thread.sleep(5000)` in the consumer after each take, see what that does

Comment: Exactly.. This is perfect. Let me understand the code flow. I will let you know for the same :) Thanks.

Comment: Check the update, it moves the `Thread.sleep` to the `Consumer`, which allows the `Producer` to run as fast as it can.  It also fills the `Producer` with 100 values instead of 10, making sure we hit that capacity limit ;)

Comment: Why did you use `while (true)` in `Consumer` ? Doesn't it mean `infinite` loop ?

Comment: Yeah it does, but I generally had no idea how many times it might need to loop and I did have the `Consumer` set as a `daemon` thread in the first example, which would allow the JVM to exit once the `Producer` thread existed ;)

Comment: Ok Thanks. You explanation helps me and will definitely helps other especially beginner to understand the `Thread`.

Answer (score 1):

Add printlns here

```
public synchronized void put(T element) throws InterruptedException {
    while (queue.size() == capacity) {
        System.out.println("blocked");
        wait();
    }
    queue.add(element);
    notify(); // notifyAll() for multiple producer/consumer threads
    System.out.println("put "+ element);
}

public synchronized T take() throws InterruptedException {
    while (queue.isEmpty()) {
        wait();
    }
    T item = queue.remove();
    notify(); // notifyAll() for multiple producer/consumer threads
    System.out.println("removed " + item);
    return item;
}
```

and run this test

```
public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {
    final BlockingQueue q = new BlockingQueue(2);
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                q.take();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        };
    }.start();
    q.put(1);
    q.put(2);  // will block here until tread 2 takes an element and reduces the capacity
    q.put(3);   
}
```

it will print

```
put 1
put 2
blocked
removed 1
put 3
```

Comment: Your code works, exactly what I was expected. But, I have one doubt, when I added another element to the queue then it get stuck and keep on waiting again. why ?

Comment: @jWeaver The queue capacity is `2`, so it's probably blocking, waiting for something to take something from the queue, but the "take" thread only removes a single item