# I don't understand how to use wait and notify on threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I've a problem with my code. I'm trying to execute two simple GUI frames (just for test purposes) in two threads. I want to wait for a thread using `wait()` and to notify using `notify()` or `notifyAll()` the second thread. I've also used `synchronized()` and did not work.

Can anyone explain to me very clear (with an example) what I'm doing wrong ? I'm new to programming and I don't know much about it. 
Thanks !

Here's my snippet:

```
public void example5() throws InterruptedException {

    Thread t = new Thread() {
    public final Object obj = new Object();
    public void run() {
          synchronized(this) {   //coordinating activities and data access among multiple threads
                                //The mechanism that Java uses to support synchronization is the monitor
               try {
                obj.wait(3000); //suspendarea thread-ului t / punerea in asteptare

            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {

            }
        JFrame frame  = new JFrame();
        JButton b = new JButton("CLICK ME 1");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(b); frame.add(panel); frame.setBounds(700, 500, 150, 100); frame.setVisible(true);
          }
    }
};

        }

Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

    public final Object obj = new Object();

        public void run() {
       obj.notify();

        JFrame frame  = new JFrame();
        JButton b = new JButton("CLICK ME 2");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(b); frame.add(panel); frame.setBounds(700, 500, 150, 100); frame.setVisible(true);
    }
});
```

Comment: I forgot one thing....i've also received an error : IllegalMonitorStateException , i've done some reasearch over the internet but i did not get it why this occurs....

Comment: You really rarely actually need to use wait and notify directly; if you don't understand them, I'd advise looking for other solutions. Check out the excellent higher level concurrency classes in the Java.util.concurrent package.

Comment: You need to synchronize to notify. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/886722/how-to-use-wait-and-notify-in-java.

Comment: Have a look at this article for better clarity on wait() and notify() concepts : http://www.journaldev.com/1037/java-thread-wait-notify-and-notifyall-example

Answer (score 1):

wait and notify should be called on the same object. Try this:

```
        Object ob1 = new Object();

    Thread t1 = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                System.out.println("ob1 tries to wait in t1...");
                synchronized (ob1) {
                    ob1.wait();
                }
                System.out.println("ob1 is up in t1!");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    Thread t2 = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);

                System.out.println("t2 tries to notify ob1's single waiter...");
                synchronized (ob1) {
                    ob1.notify();
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("t2 notified ob1's single waiter!");
        }
    };

    t1.start();
    t2.start();
```

output:

`ob1 tries to wait in t1...
t2 tries to notify ob1's single waiter...
t2 notified ob1's single waiter!
ob1 is up in t1!`

Comment: Thanks a lot guys ! You really helped me. Perfect example...easy and simple to understand. Now i know what i've done wrong...again, thanks.