# Wait And Notify IllegalMonitorStateException Anonymous Class

Tags: java, multithreading

According to [How to use wait and notify in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886722/how-to-use-wait-and-notify-in-java) I have to synchronized on the same object to call notify.

I have synchronized on the same haveCoffee object. Why I am getting IllegalMonitorStateException when I call the notify method ?

```
I am Sleeping
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.lang.Object.notify(Native Method)
    at com.example.concurrent.basic.WaitAndNotify$2.run(WaitAndNotify.java:42)
```

in the following code:

```
public class WaitAndNotify {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Thread haveCoffee = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                synchronized (this) {
                    try {
                        this.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    System.out.print("I am awake and ready to have coffee");
                }
            }
        };

        Thread me = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                synchronized (haveCoffee) {
                    try {
                        System.out.print("I am Sleeping");
                        Thread.sleep(4000);
                        notify();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        haveCoffee.start();
        me.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: you should be calling `haveCoffee.notify()` instead of `notify()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the first Thread, you call wait on an object while having its monitor (the object being this `haveCoffee`).

However, on the second thread, you call `notify()` on `me`, while having the monitor of `haveCoffee`.

This should work:

```
public class WaitAndNotify {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final Thread haveCoffee = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                synchronized (this) {
                    try {
                        this.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    System.out.print("I am awake and ready to have coffee");
                }
            }
        };

        Thread me = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                synchronized (haveCoffee) {
                    try {
                        System.out.print("I am Sleeping");
                        Thread.sleep(4000);
                        haveCoffee.notify();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        haveCoffee.start();
        me.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/886722/how-to-use-wait-and-notify-in-java states: To be able to call notify() you need to synchronize on the same object. Is that correct or does it need to  synchronize on the object you are going to call wait on ?

Comment: "To be able to call notify() you need to synchronize on the same object" is correct.  You second statement is implicit. Before calling wait() or notify() on a object, you have to synchronize the object.

Comment: you should always synchronize on an object, before calling wait/notify on it.  
Naturally, if you don't wait on the same object you call `notify()` on, you won't get the desired behavior (The waiting code will not be notified).

Comment: There is a distinct statement 1:  you need to synchronize on the same object ( could be any object) statement 2: synchronize on the object you are going to call wait on.

Comment: If you have to call  wait() on a object, it should be synchronized. Generally wait() or notify() calls are just a small part of bigger picture and synchronized protects critical section of big picture.

Answer (score 1):

From oracle documentation [page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalMonitorStateException.html),

```
public class IllegalMonitorStateException
extends RuntimeException
```

> Thrown to indicate that a thread has attempted to wait on an object's monitor or to notify other threads waiting on an object's monitor without owning the specified monitor.

Whenever you get this exception, just go through your code and check `wait()` and `notify()` calls and the `object on which these calls have been invoked`. You can easily figure out what went wrong.

**EDIT:**

`wait()` or `notify()` calls have to be invoked on object once you get monitor on that object.

Answer (score 0):

You should be calling

> haveCoffee.notify()

instead of just

> notify().

If you invoke just `notify()` it calls the `notify()` method on the `this` object which is the second thread `me` where as you have synchronized on `haveCoffee` thread and that is the reason for exception you are seeing.

So the code in thread2 `me` should looks like:

```
synchronized (haveCoffee) {
    try {
        System.out.print("I am Sleeping");
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        haveCoffee.notify();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: @ShivamSinha That is true and I believe you intended to call `notify()` on `haveCoffee` instead of just `notify()`. Please see my updated answer for the reason.