# wait() and notify() cause IllegalMonitorStateException

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, runnable, notify

I have two threads t0 and t1 with runnables posted below in the code section Run_0 and Run1 respectively. what I want to do is, when t0 is writing or doing its task that lasts for 7 seconds, t1 should be waiting. and when the 
7 seconds elapse, t1 should be notified to continue working. I tried to do that using wait() and notify() but at run time I receive the below posted errors.

please let me know how to use wait() and notify() correctly

**code**:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    t0 = new Thread(new Run_0());
    t1 = new Thread(new Run_1());

    t0.start();
    t1.start();
}

private static class Run_0 implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        while (true) {
            long startTime = TimeUtils.getTSSec();
            synchronized (this) {
                try {
                    t1.wait(); //<=========Line 27
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            System.out.println("T0 is writing");
            //simulate doing some work
            while( (TimeUtils.getTSSec()-startTime) <= 7) {

            }
            System.out.println("T0 finished writing");
            t1.notify();
            startTime = TimeUtils.getTSSec();

            while( (TimeUtils.getTSSec()-startTime) <= 7) {

            }
        }

    }

}

private static class Run_1 implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        while(true) {

            System.out.println("T1 is working");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**errors**:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Unknown Source)
at com.example.Main$Run_0.run(Main.java:27)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: You synchronize on `this`, but call wait on `t1`. BTW, you should NEVER call wait and notify on Threads.

Comment: You can ONLY `wait()` or `notify()` on a synchronized object. It doesn't allow you to just use any object.  BTW using wait/notify on a Thread is almost certainly a bug or error prone.

Comment: see accepted answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/886722/how-to-use-wait-and-notify-in-java?rq=1

Comment: See this better answer for the same question http://stackoverflow.com/a/6221775/57695

Comment: @JBNizet now I synchronized on t1, but we run the code, it always display on the ocnsole"T1 is working" only this message as if t0 has not started?

Comment: @PeterLawrey now I synchronized on t1, but we run the code, it always display on the ocnsole"T1 is working" only this message as if t0 has not started?