# java infinite wait issue?

Tags: java, synchronization, wait

code 1:

```
  class BCWCExamples  {
    public Object lock;

    boolean someCondition;

    public void NoChecking() throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized(lock) {
            //Defect due to not checking a wait condition at all
            lock.wait();  
        }
    }
```

code 2:

```
 public void IfCheck() throws InterruptedException {
            synchronized(lock) {
                // Defect due to not checking the wait condition with a loop. 
                // If the wait is woken up by a spurious wakeup, we may continue
                // without someCondition becoming true.
                if(!someCondition) { 
                    lock.wait();
                }
            }
        }
```

code 3:

```
public void OutsideLockLoop() throws InterruptedException {
            // Defect. It is possible for someCondition to become true after
            // the check but before acquiring the lock. This would cause this thread
            // to wait unnecessarily, potentially for quite a long time.
            while(!someCondition) {
                synchronized(lock) {
                    lock.wait();
                }
            }
        }
```

code 4:

```
public void Correct() throws InterruptedException {
            // Correct checking of the wait condition. The condition is checked
            // before waiting inside the locked region, and is rechecked after wait
            // returns.
            synchronized(lock) {
                while(!someCondition) {
                    lock.wait();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Note:there is notify from some other place

there is no condition for wait in code 1 so infinite wait is there , but why the infinite wait is occurring in other 3 code(2,3,4)
**kindly check the comments in the code for better understanding** kindly help me out I am new in java wait and notify

Comment: Is this the entireity of the relevant code? The value someCondition is never set to true

Answer (score 1):

I your example I don't see any `lock.notify()` or `lock.notifyAll()` invocations.

Short and simple answer: You will `wait()` unlill you call `notify()` on the same object `lock`.

For additional inforamtion please consider looking into next links:

- [How to use wait and notify in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886722/how-to-use-wait-and-notify-in-java)
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html