# Thread: notify() and wait() in java

Tags: java, multithreading

i have a simple code piece bellow:

```
public class ThreadA {
public static void main(String[] args){
    ThreadB b = new ThreadB();
    b.start();

    synchronized(b){
        try{
            System.out.println("Waiting for b to complete...");
            b.wait();
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Total is: " + b.total);
    }
}



class ThreadB extends Thread{
    int total;
    @Override
    public void run(){
        synchronized(this){
            for(int i=0; i<100 ; i++){
                total += i;
            }
            notify();
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Waiting for b to complete...
Total is: 4950
```

and i have a problem why we need use this code, i am not clearly here.

```
 synchronized(this){
        for(int i=0; i<100 ; i++){
            total += i;
        }
        notify();
    }
```

when i dont use synchronized here, i have the same result.

Comment: Without synchronized it maybe works maybe it doesn't. You are at the mercy of the thread scheduler.

Comment: Is your question about what **wait** and **notify** do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use wait and notify in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/886722/how-to-use-wait-and-notify-in-java)

Comment: @rkosegi: not a dupe. He's asking why it works without the synchronized block in ThreadB.

Answer (score 1):

When `notify()` is called and corresponding `wait()` sees that, a "happens-before" relationship is established: everything that happened in `ThreadB` prior to `notify()` will be visible in `ThreadA` after corresponding `wait()` returns. So, in your case all modifications to `total` are completed before `notify()` and it's safe to assume that `ThreadA` will see these changes.

However, note that it's incorrect way to use `wait()`/`notify()` for synchronization. There can be spurious wakeups (i.e. `wait()` waking up without corresponding `notify()`). There are specific idiomatic ways to use these methods (they're actually POSIX conditional variables in disguise). One of them is to define a "condition" which can be checked from both threads (e.g. "`is_completed` variable is `true`) and call `wait()` in a loop, see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html)

Answer (score 0):

When a thread terminates it calls `this.notifyAll()`, so your call to `notify()` in `ThreadB` isn't strictly necessary.

However, as the documentation for `Thread.join()` notes, the use of monitor operations on `Thread` objects is not recommended:

> As a thread terminates the `this.notifyAll`method is invoked. It is recommended that applications not use `wait`, `notify`, or `notifyAll` on `Thread` instances.

If you want to wait for `ThreadB` to complete, just call `b.join()` from `ThreadA`. You don't need any synchronized blocks:

```
public class ThreadA {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ThreadB b = new ThreadB();
        b.start();
        System.out.println("Waiting for b to complete...");
        b.join();
        System.out.println("Total is: " + b.total);
    }
}

public class ThreadB extends Thread {
    int total;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            total += i;
        }
    }
}
```