# Illegal monitor state Exception when two treads are waiting

Tags: java, multithreading, illegalmonitorstateexcep

HI wrote a sample program for testing the behavior of wait in java.

My implementation of Runnable:

```
class ThreadWait implements Runnable {
    Object lock = new Object();
    ThreadWait(Object lock){
        this.lock = lock;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            synchronized (lock){
                System.out.println("Started : "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
                wait();
                System.out.println("Completed : "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Used within my `main` like:

```
Object lock = new Object();
ThreadWait t1 = new ThreadWait(lock);
ThreadWait t2 = new ThreadWait(lock);
Thread a= new Thread(t1);
a.setName("A");
Thread b= new Thread(t2);
b.setName("B");
a.start();
b.start();
```

When running this program I am getting this exception:

```
Exception in thread "A" Exception in thread "B" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
Started : A
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
Started : B
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at ThreadWait.run(SynchronizedExample.java:34)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at ThreadWait.run(SynchronizedExample.java:34)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: `lock.wait()`...?

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is that you synchronized on `lock`, but you are waiting on `this` (specifically: the instance of **Runnable** that contains the wait call).

You can only call wait on objects that you own the monitor on. Your code owns `lock`, but not `this`!

So you should wait on the lock object. But please note: then your code will deadlock!

That leads to the advice: you should study the "theory" a bit more. You see, one can use wait/notify in order to "synchronize" different threads that are supposed to work on the same data; but that is not something you learn (efficiently) by trial and error; as there are simply too many subtle details that influence the outcome of trial and error experiments. You might start reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886722/how-to-use-wait-and-notify-in-java) or [there](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html).

One final word: it is also important to understand that, yes, wait/notify are important concepts; but you rarely use them in "the real world". These are very low-level mechanisms, and Java has added more powerful abstractions on top of them.

Comment: thank you that fixed the issue, and yes I am trying to create deadlock.