# 'Implicit' synchronization in java?

Tags: java, synchronization

when I have a method like

```
public void unsynchronizedMethod(){
  callSynchronizedMethod();
  //dosomestuff after this line
}
```

does it mean that all content, after calling callSynchronizedMethod() in the unsynchronizedMethod()-Method, is implicitly synchronized?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Synchronization is defined in a straightforward manner:

- For a `synchronized` method: within the execution of that method
- For a `synchronized` block: within the execution of that block

Here are the relevant excerpts from *Java Language Specification 3rd Edition*:

#### [JLS 14.19 The `synchronized` Statement](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.19)

> A `synchronized` statement:
>
> 1. acquires a mutual-exclusion lock on behalf of the executing thread,
> 2. executes a block,
> 3. then releases the lock.
>
> While the executing thread owns the lock, no other thread may acquire the lock.

`synchronized` methods is semantically identical to a `synchronized` statement applied to the whole method ([§JLS 8.4.3.6](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.4.3.6). The lock is obtained from either `this` (if it's an instance method) or the [`Class`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) object associated with the method's class (if it's a `static` method; you can't refer to `this` in a `static` context).

So to answer the original question, given this snippet:

```
public void unsynchronizedMethod(){
  callSynchronizedMethod();

  doSomeUnsynchronizedStuff(); // no "implicit synchronization" here
}
```

Note that this is by design: you should always strive to minimize synchronization to only critical sections. Outside of those critical sections, there is no lingering effect from earlier synchronization.

#### See also

- *Effective Java 2nd Edition, Item 67: Avoid excessive synchronization*

#### Related questions

- [What is the difference between a synchronized method and synchronized block in Java ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149928/what-is-the-difference-between-a-synchronized-method-and-synchronized-block-in-ja)
- [synchronized block vs synchronized method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574240/synchronized-block-vs-synchronized-method)

Answer (score 7):

No. The lock is released at the end of `callSynchronizedMethod()`.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not.

Synchronized means that only one thread at a time will execute the code.

But after `callSynchronizedMethod()` the threads could run again over the code in different order, all at at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

No, there wont be an implicit synchronisation. Synchronized works within a block or function scope. Anything outside a synchronized block is not synchronized.

The following example code shows that. If the methods where synchronized it would always print 0.

```
class example extends Thread{
   //Global value updated by the example threads
   public static volatile int value= 0;
    public void run(){
    while(true)//run forever
       unsynchMethod();

   }
   public void unsynchMethod(){
     synchronizedMethod();
    //Count value up and then back down to 0
    for(int i =0; i < 20000;++i)
       value++;//reads increments and updates value (3 steps)
    for(int i = 0; i < 20000;++i)
       value--;//reads decrements and updates value (3 steps)
      //Print value 
      System.out.println(value);
   }
   //Classlevel synchronized function
   public static synchronized void synchronizedMethod(){
      //not important
   }
   public static void main(String... args){
    example a = new example();
    example b = new example();
    a.start();
    b.start();
   }

}
```

My Results, should have been 0 if synchronized:

```
4463
6539
-313
-2401
-3012
...
```