# What is the difference between a synchronized function and synchronized block?

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, synchronized

what is the difference between

```
public synchronized void addition()
{
   //something;
}
```

and

```
public void addtion()
{
     synchronized (//something)
     {
        //something;
     }
}
```

If I am wrong Ignore this question.

Comment: Possible [dupplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149928/what-is-the-difference-between-a-synchronized-method-and-synchronized-block-in-j)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it the first one only one thread can execute whole method at a time whereas in second one  only one thread can execute that synchronized block if not used **this** as parameter.

here is a duplicate of it [Is there an advantage to use a Synchronized Method instead of a Synchronized Block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574240/synchronized-block-vs-synchronized-method)

Answer (score 5):

```
public synchronized void addition() {...}
```

is equivalent to

```
public void addition() {
  synchronized(this) { ... }
}
```

Now, if you replace the `this` with a different object reference, the locking will be done using that other object's monitor.

Answer (score 2):

The second one doesn't compile. If you meant

```
public void addition()
{
     synchronized (this)
     {
        //something;
     }
}
```

Then they're equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

If the second example is `synchronized (this)`, then there's no difference. If it's something else, then the lock object is different.

Answer (score 2):

```
public synchronized void addition()
{
   //something;
}
```

is the same as:

```
public void addtion()
{
     synchronized (this)
     {
        //something;
     }
}
```

Whereas, in your second example, you may want to synchronize using something different from `this`.

Answer (score 0):

Synchronized method synchronizes on "this" object. And if it is a block you can choose any object as a lock.

Answer (score 0):

I)

```
public synchronized void addition() 
{
    //something; 
}
```

II)

```
public void addtion() 
{      
    synchronized (//something)      
    {
        //something;      
    }
}
```

In version I (`method level synchronization`), at a time, complete body of method can only be executed by one thread only.

however, version II is more flexible cause it's called `block level synchronization` and you can add some lines above `synchronized (//something)` to execute them parallely. it should be `synchronized (this)`

version II should be preferred as only that code needs to be multithreaded (within synchronized) which are critical.