# Double-checked locking of non-null class member field

Tags: java, synchronization, member, weak-references, double-checked-locking

I'm aware of the classic [double-checked locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking) idiom for [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3580658/1391325), which first checks if a given field is `null` and, if so, acquires a lock on the class which has the field:

```
// Double-check idiom for lazy initialization of instance fields
// See Pascal Thivent's original answer <https://stackoverflow.com/a/3580658/1391325>
private volatile FieldType field;

FieldType getField() {
    FieldType result = field;
    if (result == null) { // First check (no locking)
        synchronized(this) {
            result = field;
            if (result == null) { // Second check (with locking)
                field = result = computeFieldValue();
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

However, in the case that `field` will never be null (instead referencing "[null object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern)" value which is lazily replaced with a "non-null object"), can the synchronization on `this` be refined to `synchronized(field)`?

### Example

I've got a single, very large `HugeObject` which can nevertheless be easily re-created. I want the garbage collector to be able to discard this instance in cases where memory is starting to run out, so I hold it with a `Reference<HugeObject>`, and initialize it to `Reference<HugeObject> field = new SoftReference<>(null)`. I'd prefer avoiding a lock on the entire object `this` so that using methods which don't affect the state of `field` can be called even during initialization of `field`. Would it then be possible to simply acquire a lock on *either* this initial "null object" *or* the already-instantiated "non-null object", or could this result in subtle, unwanted concurrency effects? See code below:

```
private volatile Reference<HugeObject> field = new SoftReference<>(null);

HugeObject getField() {
    HugeObject result = field.get();
    if (result == null) {
        synchronized(field) {
            result = field.get();
            if (result == null) {
                result = computeFieldValue();
                field = new SoftReference<>(result);
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: The monitor used for you synchronized block is not constant - that's doesn't look right. What is the problem with synchronizing on `this` (or a `private final Object lock - new Object();`)?

Comment: I'd prefer avoiding a lock on the entire object `this` so that using methods which don't affect the state of `field` can be called even during initialization of `field`. However, I never thought about using a lock/mutex object; That could be an answer I'd accept.

Comment: I would like to highlight that synchronizing on the entire object `this` does not influence the  "methods which don't affect the state of `field`", i.e. calling these methods will block only if they contain the `synchronized(this)`; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11981227/synchronizedthis-blocks-whole-object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to synchronize on `this`, you can use another reference. But that reference needs to be constant. In your example, you are locking on `field` which gets reassigned - so two threads could execute your method concurrently if they have different values for `field`.

One standard solution is to use a dedicated lock:

```
private final Object lock = new Object();

//...

synchronized(lock) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

You definitely do not want to lock on a null mutable member. Most people lock on `this` or the class. But if you do not want to do that, the solution by assylias works well for your use case. You can also look through the `java.util.concurrent.locks` package. It provides ways of doing locking manually without using the `synchronized` block. Maybe a `ReentrantLock` would work for you? The package also has some cool things like condition variables and spin locks (probably not what you would use here though). Also, I wrote an article on the singleton pattern and the use of double-checked locking and the "holder" pattern that might be interesting to you. https://medium.com/@michael.andrews/deconstructing-the-singleton-b5f881f85f5