# Synchronized Methods

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

If I have a synchronized public method and a private method:

```
public synchronized void doSomething() {
    doSomethingElse()
}

private void doSomethingElse() {
}
```

Do I need to synchronize the private method?

Comment: Depends on what you want them to do, and if they should be allowed to run concurrently.

Answer (score 18):

It depends:

- If `doSomethingElse` is safe to call concurrently, then you don't need `synchronized`.
- If it isn't, then the answer depends on where it is called from:

  - If it is only called from other `synchronized` methods, then it doesn't need to be `synchronized` (but marking it as such will do no harm);
  - If it can be called from methods that aren't `synchronized` themselves, then it *must* be `synchronized`.

Answer (score 5):

**NO:** if the only way `doSomethingElse()` is called is through another method that IS synchronized.

**Possibly YES:** If you call `doSomethingElse()` in some other fashion, through a method that is not synchronized, and you need to protect it against concurrent access.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on what you're doing.  Do you need to ensure serial access to `doSomethingElse()`?

If so, and the only thing calling `doSomethingElse()` is `doSomething()`, then no, you don't need to synchronize.  But if some other method can call `doSomethingElse()`, then yes, you should synchronize it also.

Answer (score 3):

This is the intent of the `@GuardedBy` annotation. If you expect that a lock *must* be held when calling that method, annotate it with that and the name of the lock (in the example it would be:

```
@GuardedBy("this") private void doSomethingElse() {…}
```

Then you can check that the invariant is true with FindBugs.

You can also use the [other `net.jcip.annotations`](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/api/net/jcip/annotations/package-summary.html) for describing the thread-safety or lack of it and have FindBugs validate these assumptions too. Of course, [the book](http://www.javaconcurrencyinpractice.com/) needs a plug as well.

Answer (score 2):

Any methods called from a synchronized method (or from within a `synchronized` block) are run while still synchronized. You don't need to separately synchronize the private method if it is only called from synchronized methods.

Answer (score 1):

If you synchronize a block of code then anything called from within that block of code (on the same thread) still holds the initial lock.  So `doSomethingElse` is still a part of the synchronized block when it is called from `doSomething`.

If you did:

```
public synchronized void doSomething() {
  new Thread() {
    public void run() {
      doSomethingElse();
    }
  }.start();
}
private void doSomethingElse() {
}
```

Then `doSomethingElse` would **not** have the lock that was acquired by `doSomething`.

Also avoid synchronized methods as it exposes the implementation details of your concurrency policy.  See this question on synchronized(this) / synchronized methods: [Avoid synchronized(this) in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442564/avoid-synchronizedthis-in-java)

If `doSomethingElse` must be synchronized, regardless of whether or not it is called from `doSomething`, it wouldn't hurt to synchronize `doSomethingElse` as synchronized locks are re-entrant (i.e., if a thread already has a lock on an object it can get the lock again).

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I do not like synchronized methods. I prefer to synchronize with some kind of lock varaible, as so:

```
private final Object lock = new Object();

public void doSomething() {
  synchronized(lock) {
    // Do some safely
    doSomethingElse();
  }
  // Do some work un-safely
}

private void doSomethingElse() {
  // Do some work safely because still in lock above
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although what you've done is fine, in my opinion, synchronization should be done at the lowest granularity possible. Which would suggest to synchronize the actual private function. Currently, you're assuming that no other function in the class will call the private function independently. This may not be the case in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the code works correctly when the private method is not synchronized, it would seem prudent from a maintainability perspective to make the private method synchronized.

Intrinsic locks are re-entrant, there is no harm in adding the synchronized keyword to the private method.

Putting code in a private method invites letting it be called by other methods, so it would make sense to make the private method synchronized in case in the future it is called from another method that does not otherwise need to be synchronized.