# synchronized(this) and observers notifications

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, locking, observer-pattern

This is related, but definitely not identical, to this famous SO question:

[Avoid synchronized(this) in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442564)

Very often I've got an "observable subject" that likes to notify its observers when it is modified.  The notification is basically making "alien method" calls (as they're called in *Effective Java* etc.) I may have something like this:

```
public void updateData(params) {
    synchronized (this) {
        // do some computation here
    }
    notifyObservers(); // Never, EVER, call an alien method with a lock held (see Effective Java)
}

public synchronized Result getResult() {
   ...
}
```

Should I be avoiding the `synchronized(this)` and hence also remove the `synchronized` from the `getResult()` method?

Is this the following that people advising against `synchronized(this)` are recommending:

```
private final Object lock = new Object(); // shiny lock

public void updateDate(params) {
    synchronized( lock ) {
       ...
    }
    notifyObservers();
}

public Result getResult() {
    synchronized( lock ) {
        return Result;
    }
}
```

As a bonus question that doesn't warrant it's own SO question: if the latter is recommended, what do people who advise against using *synchronized(this)* think about the fact that methods in Java can be declared as "synchronized"?

Comment: Note that if using a private lock is preferred in this observers/notification case, I've got absolutely zero problem switching my code to the "private lock" idiom :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are concerned about exposing your lock, you don't want to make it a part of your API or you have a finer-grained locking policy and one lock isn't enough, you could use use a private lock as you described.

Note however that there is another, much more flexible alternative: [`ReentrantLock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html). One of the disadvantages of intrinsic locks not mentioned in the question which you referred to is that they only support uninterruptible lock acquisition. On the other hand, `ReentrantLock` provides methods for checking lock status, interruptible acquisition and acquisition with a timeout.

Interruptible acquisition is particularly useful when writing cancelable tasks since it follows the [general prescription](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05236/index.html) for blocking methods to throw InterruptedException to signal thread interruption in a blocking operation. The cancelation mechanism based on interruption is followed by [Executors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) from [java.util.concurrent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html).