# Set up a Fiveton class to be accessed by different threads in round-robin fashion

Tags: java, multithreading

Similar to Singleton class I want to create a Fiveton class which can create maximum 5 instances of the class. Different threads are trying to access instances of this class (hence getInstance method needs to be provided). However class is heavy so the instances must not be eagerly created i.e. created on demand.

Also contract is that threads are allotted instances in round robin fashion i.e. Thread no.1, 6, 11 get instance 1 of Fiveton object. If the instance is being used by a thread, they wait for the lock (it may be possible that thread 6 and 11 wait for instance 1 and thread 11 may get it but in no circumstance thread 11 should get instance 2). Similarly, Thread no. 2, 7, 12 should get instance 2.

Comment: What are your thoughts on how to achieve this?

Comment: You can use the new java.concurrent classes for locks on each object. Plus each thread needs a id notion and which object it should get based on id. Can use a util class that takes your Runnable that is running on one of the 5 threads, looks at its id, asks lock and waits for correct object that is in a static list.

Comment: i also want ontract is that threads are allotted instances in round robin fashion i.e. Thread no.1, 6, 11 get instance 1 of Fiveton object. If the instance is being used by a thread, they wait for the lock (it may be possible that thread 6 and 11 wait for instance 1 and thread 11 may get it but in no circumstance thread 11 should get instance 2). Similarly, Thread no. 2, 7, 12 should get instance 2.

Answer (score 3):

Don't code that in your class itself*, instead, use an object pool.

A good library to get you started is [Apache Commons / Pool](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/)

Another one I don't know but that claims to be faster is [furious-objectpool](https://code.google.com/p/furious-objectpool/)

Use one of the supplied implementations or use the libraries as a basis to build your own custom pool.

* Why not code that into the class itself? Because what a class does and how to get access to instances of a class are unrelated concerns. The class should concentrate on it's core purposes and not about managing itself.

Comment: But this wont take care of thread 1, 6, 11 getting object 1. Unless you have 5 pools with 1 object and the specific code in the threads asking the correct pool for the object. Pools do not block in definately too. Need a lock and wait logic for this

Comment: I don't think a typical object pool will satisfy the cyclicality requirement.

Comment: That's why I wrote "Use one of the supplied implementations or use the libraries as a basis to build your own custom pool"

Comment: well i don't think a pool be optimal. need to be handled separately and generically .  but via a object array in an SingleObjectServer and individual locks.

Comment: can anyone give me custom code for this .

Comment: i need java code for the above problem,have to do in my project .

Comment: the given archive will not do Thread no.1, 6, 11 get instance 1 of Fiveton object. If the instance is being used by a thread, they wait for the lock (it may be possible that thread 6 and 11 wait for instance 1 and thread 11 may get it but in no circumstance thread 11 should get instance 2). Similarly, Thread no. 2, 7, 12 should get instance 2.

Comment: supprse thread 1 came into syncronise block ,one object created and added into list.same for 2,3,4 ..1) what for fifth thread .... and how these thead will use the object and when 1 is using how 6 will wait

Comment: for the fifth thread the same thing happens as for 1,2,3,4 : "one object created and added into list" because you wanted to use 5 instances (0-4) so thread 5 has instance no. 0

Comment: +1 for "what a class does and how to get access to instances of a class are unrelated concerns."

Answer (score 1):

If you care about contention while instances are created (i.e. you don't want Thread 6 to block because Thread 2 is still creating its instance), you can use a lock striping strategy - in this implementation, it is assumed that Thread 1, 2, ... call `getInstance` one after the other:

```
class CyclicFiveton {

    private static final CyclicFiveton[] fivetons = new CyclicFiveton[5];
    private static final Object[] locks = new Object[5];
    private static final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();

    static {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            locks[i] = new Object();
        }
    }

    private CyclicFiveton() {
    }

    public static CyclicFiveton getInstance() {
        int index = counter.getAndIncrement() % 5;
        synchronized (locks[index]) {
            CyclicFiveton fiveton = fivetons[index];
            if (fiveton == null) {
                fiveton = new CyclicFiveton();
                fivetons[index] = fiveton;
            }
            return fiveton;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why did you used synchronized (locks[index])? instead you could use  synchronized (fivetons[index]) right?

Comment: @Stephan It is usually better practice to synchronize on a field that is not accessible/synchronizable by a client to the API.  In this situation synchronizing on `fivetons[index]` synchronizes on the same instance that is returned.  You can read more here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442564/avoid-synchronizedthis-in-java

Comment: @assylias +1, but wouldn't it make sense to use a `ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, CyclicFiveton>` and use the built in synchronization?

Comment: @JohnVint +1 yeah ur right, plus the fact that using synchronized on `fivetons[index]` you will not be able to do the lazy initialization

Comment: @Stephan `fivetons[index]` could be null.

Comment: @JohnVint Not sure you can achieve "full laziness" (putIfAbsent will need to pre-create the object and you might end up creating it twice).

Comment: @assylias You're right - missed his need to make it lazy

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you requirements correctly you can try something like this:

```
public class Fiveton {

private Fiveton(){
    //create private constructor to prevent new instances from outside of the class
}

private static final int MAX_NB_INSTANCES = 5;
private static List<Fiveton> instances; 

/**
 * Should be called once at the beginning 
 */
public static void init(){
    instances =  new ArrayList<Fiveton>(MAX_NB_INSTANCES);
    for(int i=0;i<MAX_NB_INSTANCES;i++){
        instances.add(new Fiveton());
    }
}

/**
 *  threadNb can be the name of the Thread::getName() 
 * 
 * @param threadNb
 * @return Fiveton
 */
public static Fiveton getInstance(int threadNb){
    synchronized(instances.get(threadNb%MAX_NB_INSTANCES)){
        return instances.get(threadNb%MAX_NB_INSTANCES);
    }       
}  

/**
 * other logic
 * 
 */
```

}

All you need is to add the logic behind the Fiveton object.

**UPDATE**

Or as ***Sean Patrick Floyd*** well pointed out you can use this just to manage the instances and have a different class (object) for the logic that you want its much cleaner and transparent this way.

**UPDATE**

Added lazy initialization

Comment: The op wants lazy initialization.

Comment: @assylias : thx, i missed that ... anyway its easy to implement the lazy initialization : 

1. remove init method

2. in get instance method you check if the instance you want (threadNb%MAX_NB_INSTANCES) exists and if not create it

Comment: what about thread access;Thread no.1, 6, 11 get instance 1 of Fiveton object. If the instance is being used by a thread, they wait for the lock (it may be possible that thread 6 and 11 wait for instance 1 and thread 11 may get it but in no circumstance thread 11 should get instance 2). Similarly, Thread no. 2, 7, 12 should get instance 2.

Comment: this is achieved by threadNb%MAX_NB_INSTANCES : thread no.1 -> 1%5=1 it gets instance 1 , thread no.6 -> 6%5=1 it gets instance 1 etc so there is no way for thread no. 11 to get instance 2. Clear now? or you had another problem?

Comment: thanks, but one question on this .. what if thread 1 using instance one .. then thread 6 and 11 have to wait .. where is logic for that ...i mean " If the instance is being used by a thread, they wait for the lock (it may be possible that thread 6 and 11 wait for instance 1"  what about this logic

Comment: for first question : since the method is synchronized thread 6 and 11 will wait till thread 1 gets the instance . Isn't that what you what?

Comment: for second question 5%5=0 so it will receive instance no. 0 . you have 5 instances from 0 to 4

Comment: if method is syncronise ... then when thread 1 geting instance,other all will wait ..after 1 if 2 get into the method and instance one is not accessing by thread 1,then also 6 and other have to wait .... as method if syncronise

Comment: second as per problem :If the instance is being used by a thread, they wait for the lock (it may be possible that thread 6 and 11 wait for instance 1 ) .. means 6 and 11 only have to wait for one .not others ... but as per the suggested implementation method is only access by one method at a time... so when thread 2 is using it that time also 6 and 11 waiting

Comment: what about round robin ...

Comment: i got ur point so i've updated the logic and now you have synchronized  only on the instance you need so for example thread 2 will not wait for thread 1 . is it ok for you?

Comment: well it implements round robin principle : you have even distribution and also circular order 1->1,2->2,3->3,4->4,5->0,6->1 etc

Comment: i am sorry but still bit confusion . as per need it says thread 1 uses till than 6 wait . but in this given code where we having multiple thread and using instance ..it just creating

Comment: what do you mean by using instance ? i assumed you just needed to return that instance

Comment: i mean the code who use the above code.... a kind of testing

Comment: and how the above code is round robin

Comment: i assumed you mean this : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_scheduling . "As the term is generally used, time slices are assigned to each process in equal portions and in circular order, handling all processes without priority" since every thread i assume will have the same things to do the you can say "time slices are assigned to each process in equal portions" , here we have circular order due to %5 and all threads have the same prio (FIFO)

Comment: ok thanks .. so by default it will be round robin

Comment: @user2247776 : yes and the same principle is applied also int the solution proposed by `assylias` only that he has a better synchronization system so i recommend to use his solution

Comment: but again ... its not lazy loading

Comment: thanks for giving the solution but I also want each thread's run method and it should go on sleep after taking lock on object and then other corrosponding thread must wait (if 1's run method took lock n went sleep ,6 11 should in waiting mode)

Comment: if you acquire the lock with a thread and another thread wants to acquire the same lock the by default it will wait until the lock is released . if you want to put the thread to sleep after it acquired the lock (even though i do not see the purpose for this) you could use the solution provided by @assylias