# Java Thread notify not called

Tags: java, android

I am trying to use thread wait and notify function, but noticed that notify function not calling my method again. Sharing my code. Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Thread t;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                List<Parent> threadList = new ArrayList<>();
                threadList.add(new Task1(MainActivity.this));
                threadList.add(new Task2(MainActivity.this));
                for (Parent task : threadList) {
                    try {
                        task.execute();
                        t.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
         t.start();
    }

    public void getResult(int i) {
        Log.i("@@@","Notified"+i);
        t.notify();
    }
}
```

```
class Task1 implements Parent{
    public int total;
    MainActivity mainActivity;
    Task1 (MainActivity c) {
        mainActivity = c;
    }
    @Override
    public void execute() {
        for(int i=0; i<200 ; i++){
            total += i;
            Log.i("@@@1", ""+i);
        }
        mainActivity.getResult(1);
    }
}
```

Task 2 is not getting executed after Task1

Comment: There is so much wrong with your code, I'm not sure where to start... You should **never** call `wait()` on a `Thread` instance, you can also only ever call `wait` or `notify` if you have synchronized on the object in question (again, which you should **never** do on a `Thread`). Your task currently probably fails with an exception anyway because of that. Also given you execute task1 and task2 sequentially on a single thread, you should never wait **at all**, because the subsequent task will never execute.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16197135/how-can-the-wait-and-notify-methods-be-called-on-objects-that-are-not-thread

Comment: you are not creating different threads. So `task.execute();` is called which calls `mainActivity.getResult(1);` which calls `t.notify();`. This all happens before actual call to `t.wait();` so thread is notified before any wait is added. so now, its waiting for another notify which never happens.