# Synchronized Circular Queue

Tags: java, thread-safety, queue, deadlock, synchronized

I am implementing a very simple synchronized `Circular Queue` as it follows , a friend of mine says that it's prone to `deadlock` ! but I don't believe so ,

actually when a thread wants to dequeue (poll) if the queue is empty it has to wait until another thread enqueue (offer) an element and vice versa if the queue is full ,

I am not very good at finding deadlock-prone codes, do you think that it's prone to deadlock too ?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class CircularQueue<T>{
    ArrayList<T> q;
    int front , rear , size;
    public CircularQueue(int size){
        q = new ArrayList<T>();
        for (int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)
            q.add(null);
        front =  0;
        rear =0;
        this.size = size;
     }
     public void offer(T t) throws InterruptedException{
        synchronized(this){
            if ( (rear + 1) % size == front)
                this.wait();    
        }
        rear = (rear + 1) % size;
        q.set(rear, t);
        this.notify();
     }
     public T poll() throws InterruptedException{
        synchronized(this){
            if (rear == front)
                this.wait();
        }
        front = (front+1) % size;
        T result = q.get(front);
        this.notify();
        return result;
     }
}
```

Comment: `this.notify()` will always throw `IllegalMonitorStateException` because it is not synchronized

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but isn't this quite the same as a [bounded BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html)?
Your implementation is under-synchronized leading to unintended behaviour. For example, two threads may concurrently change `front` in the `poll()` method.

Comment: @Adam Siemion : Is this because it's possible that no thread is waiting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your implementation:

- The call of `notify()` must come from inside a `synchronized` block
- Your implementation creates "lingerers" - a kind of Java memory leak, when objects are prevented from being collected for longer than they should be. To fix this, set the element that you return from `poll()` to `null`.
- You do not need to use `ArrayList<T>` and fill it with `null`s; a plain array of `Object` would be sufficient. You would need to add casting, but it's going to be there anyway, with or without `ArrayList`, so you might as well move it into your code.
- [You should not synchronize on `this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442564/avoid-synchronizedthis-in-java).

This last point allows malicious users of your queue permanently stall the progress by synchronizing on the queue object itself, and not releasing a lock.

Comment: Disagree about synchronizing on `this`: in a low-level utility like this one I don't think it's a problem. A user of this class should always instantiate it privately so that no one else can get a lock on it, though.

Comment: regarding your third note , but it's not possible to instantiate a generic array ! is it ?

Comment: @ArianHosseinzadeh: just create an array of the erased type, which in this case is Object. It will work due to array covariance, but you'll get a warning you'll have to suppress.

Comment: So you mean something like this : 
T[] q = (T[])new Object[size];

Comment: @DanielPryden It's better be safe than sorry: an extra `Object myLock = new Object()` is a small price to pay for making some of your implementation details inaccessible to outsiders.

Comment: @ArianHosseinzadeh Or even `Object[] q = new Object[size]()` and `T result = (T)q[front];`

Comment: @ArianHosseinzadeh: Yes. You'll need a `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` as well, to tell the compiler you know what you're doing. Or, as dasblinkenlight says, just cast at the point of access.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: conversely, though, synchronizing on `this` allows other classes to perform multiple operations on objects of this class in a thread-safe way. This is why many of the Java standard library classes synchronize on `this`. So I don't think it's strictly wrong, although I agree that it's better to be safe than sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You need to synchronize your entire methods, not just the wait() calls.

Imagine what would happen if two threads both tried to offer() at the same time, when there are two slots left. They could both pass the synchronized block and then read different values for rear on the next line. Then the next call to poll() would block but the value would already be there.

There are a few other issues with this code as well: you don't handle spurious wakeups and you call notify() outside without holding the monitor.  Also, I would use an Object[] instead of an ArrayList here, since a fixed-size mutable collection is exactly what you want.

Comment: So do you mean that I have to make both of the methods (poll & offer) as synchronized ? what do I have to wait on then ? because as I said I want to wait until someone enqueues something into the queue (in case of dequeuing)

Comment: You need to wait() with a timeout in a loop, while checking the condition. You don't necessarily want the whole method synchronized, but you need to synchronize the read-modify-write operation so you don't have to race another thread. You may find the AtomicInteger class handy for this purpose.