# Java: why does this work?

Tags: java, android

It is a possibly dumb question, probability my Java is just rudimentary :-(
but I do not understand why this works (it is actually Android code, but I think this as a general Java question).

I do not understand how is it possible that the object `mySensorEventListener` is actually created???

- I do not understand what does this code below actually do.
- How does this code get called???
- When is it called???

### THIS IS THE PART I DO NOT UNDERSTAND

```
public SensorListener mySensorEventListener = new SensorListener() {

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(int sensor, float[] values) {
        synchronized (this) {
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(int sensor, int accuracy) {
    }
};
```

---

---

### And this is the android Activity it belongs to:

```
public class RouteMapActivity extends Activity implements IRegisterReceiver {
private SensorManager mSensorManager;
private MapView mapView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mapView = new MapView(this, provider.getTileSource()
            .getTileSizePixels(), resProxy, provider);

    mSensorManager=(SensorManager)getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mSensorManager.registerListener(mySensorEventListener,
            SensorManager.SENSOR_ORIENTATION,
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);

    setContentView(mapView);
}

public SensorListener mySensorEventListener = new SensorListener() {

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(int sensor, float[] values) {
        synchronized (this) {
            float mHeading = values[0];
            mapView.setMapOrientation(-mHeading);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(int sensor, int accuracy) {
    }
};
```

Comment: "_There is no new!!!_" It's in the first line of the code you posted. `mySensorEventListener = new SensorListener()`

Comment: There is `new` there.. it's in the first line

Comment: `public SensorListener mySensorEventListener = new SensorListener() {`

Comment: Have a look at this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

Comment: mySensorEventListener is a field with new initialized, when RouteMapActivity is created.

Answer (score 7):

> There is no new

As pointed out in comments, there is a `new` in the first line, this kind of instantiation is called [**Anonymous Class**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html).

> I do not understand what does this code below actually do.

The `synchronized` block makes sure that notification of change in the sensors are not handled simultaneously, but one after the other.

> How does this code get called???
>   When is it called???

This code gets called by the `SensorManager` upon changes in the [orientation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#SENSOR_ORIENTATION). This is what it was registered for:

```
mSensorManager.registerListener(mySensorEventListener,
        SensorManager.SENSOR_ORIENTATION,
        SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
```

Comment: Nice answer, but IMHO you should also point out that `synchronized(this)` is usually [not a very good idea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442564/avoid-synchronizedthis-in-java).

Comment: Thanks MB, I am not sure I understand when `public SensorListener mySensorEventListener = new SensorListener() {...etc...` gets called, I see the `new` now :-) still do not get when the object is created

Comment: the `new` operator means object creation. Since this code is not inside a method but inside the class, and since this object is not static, it is created when the enclosing object (your `RouteMapActivity`) is created.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the reason you're confused is that you don't realize that the stuff between the { ... } braces is the creating of a class without the formal ...

```
public class SensorListener {

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(int sensor, float[] values) {
     synchronized (this) {
     }
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(int sensor, int accuracy) {
}

}
```

then in your code you'd see ...

```
public SensorListener mySensorEventListener = new SensorListener();
```

Perhaps you don't realize that what you have above is the same as what I've written here.
Does that help?

Comment: Thanks KSK :-) but still don't get it :-( Now I understand that the stuff between the braces is a class definition, and I see the `new` but when/how does it get instantiated? Thanks KSK

Comment: The `new SensorListener()` is called before the constructor of the `RouteMapActivity` class would be called.  It may be helpful to you (if you can) to step through your code with a good debugger.  You'll see this line be executed just before the `RouteMapActivity` contructor (if there is one) is called.  In other words, when the `RouteMapActivity` is instantiated, then the `SensorListener` is instantiated immediately thereafter.