# Add numbers using 5 threads

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

Question : I have to create 5 threads where each thread has to perform the addition operation.

- Thread1 - Add 1 to 10
- Thread2 - Add 1 to 50
- Thread3 - Add 5 to 15
- Thread4 - Add 10 to 20
- Thread5 - Add 15 to 20

What is the best way to accomplish this?  Also, I need 1 sec time delay between each addition operation. I have written this code: 
My output is wrong and changing every time. I know problem is with synchronized but not able solve.

```
class adding implements Runnable{
    int a,b; 
    public adding(int a, int b){
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
    public void run() {
        add(a,b);
    }
    public void add(int a, int b){
        int sum=0;
        synchronized (this) {
            for(int i=a;i<=b;i++){
                sum = sum+ a;
            }
            System.out.println("Sum of "+a+" to "+ b+" numbers = "+sum);    
        }
    }
}

public class addnumbersusing5threads {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new adding(1,10));
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new adding(1,50));
        Thread t3 = new Thread(new adding(5,15));
        Thread t4 = new Thread(new adding(10,20));
        Thread t5 = new Thread(new adding(15,20));
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
        t4.start();
        t5.start();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Sum of 1 to 10 numbers = 10  
Sum of 1 to 50 numbers = 50 
Sum of 5 to 15 numbers = 55 
Sum of 10 to 20 numbers = 110 
Sum of 15 to 20 numbers = 90
```

Comment: You need to synchronize around both reads and writes of a and b if you want to use monitors as mutex guards.  (Also please make your class names start with a CapitalLetter!)

Comment: Do you want the results to appear in exactly this order (1 to 10, then 1 to 50, etc.), or the order is irrelevant as long as there is a one second delay between operations?

Comment: Order doesn't matter but what if it matters? Can you explain both the approaches?

Comment: I think for maintaining the order, thread joins would be used.

Comment: @BadZen `a` and `b` are _local variables_.  They are not visible to more than one thread, and so they need no synchronization.

Comment: `synchronized (this)` has absolutely no effect in this program:  A `synchronized` block has no effect until more than one thread attempts to synchronize on the same object, but that never happens in this program:  Each of your threads has its own instance of the `adding` class to work on, and they never interact with one another.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

here is the problem:

```
sum = sum + a;
```

it should be `sum += i;`

BTW, you don't need any synchronization here

if you want delay between additions - use `Thread.sleep(1000L);`

Comment: You need synchronization to implement a 1s delay between calculations, I believe.

Comment: That, or you take the print statements out of the `Thread` implementation and have the caller wait for each thread to complete and then print the results in the desired order/with the desired timing.

Comment: @FreeNickname  The simplest way for any thread to wait for one second is to call `Thread.sleep(1000)`.  That's not "synchronization" because it does not affect any thread other than the one that calls it.

Comment: @jameslarge, It depends on the task interpretation. I guess, that you assume, that there should be a 1 second delay between every `sum = sum+ a;` operation. In this case I would agree with you. However, I believe, that the task asks to add a pause between calls to the `add()` function (it is more probable, since the task seems to be devoted to thread synchronization), and every call to the `add()` function is performed on a separate thread. So, we have to synchronize them.

Answer (score 3):

As per Lashane, there is no need to synchronize here - there is no contention on `sum` as each thread will have its own variable. (And if you do need to synchronize, [don't synchronize on `this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442564/avoid-synchronizedthis-in-java) as the object reference has scope outside of the class and could e.g. be subject to deadlock - instead, synchronize on a private field object, e.g. `private final Object lock = new Object();`)

```
 public void add(int a, int b){
    int sum=0;
    for(int i=a;i<=b;i++){
        sum = sum + i;
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
    System.out.println("Sum of "+a+" to "+ b+" numbers = "+sum);
}
```

Also, after starting threads, you will need to join them back into the main thread.

```
...
t4.start();
t5.start();
// Join
t1.join();
t2.join();
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `Thread.sleep(1000L)` to your add method

```
   public void add(int a, int b) throws InterruptedException {
        int sum=0;
        synchronized (this) {
            for(int i=a;i<=b;i++){
                sum += i;
                Thread.sleep(1000L); // Add this line for one second delay on each addition
            }
            System.out.println("Sum of "+a+" to "+ b+" numbers = "+sum);

        }
    }
```