# How to make all class methods run only on single thread? (synchronized class?)

Tags: java, multithreading, sqlite, jdbc, synchronized

I know `synchronized` keyword makes method run only on single class at a time. But here is the problem.

I have a database class with methods e.g. `insertAccount`, `updateSetting`, etc. If I make `insertAccount`, `updateSetting` synchronized, each of them will be able to run only on one thread at a time.

If there was one method for whole database, it would be great, but there are not one. If one thread calls `insertAccount` and another thread calls `updateSetting` **at the same time**, it will go bad, right?

Because only one of these methods can be run at any time. So what do I do?

Is there a way to apply something like `synchronized` to the whole class? So that if 1st thread calls `insertAccount` and 2nd thread calls `updateSetting` at the same time, 2nd thread has to wait until 1st thread finishes accessing database.

Comment: You should use a lock mechanism, such a semaphore

Comment: You should rely on (correct use of) database transactions with an appropriate transaction isolation level instead, then it will even work if you have multiple nodes hosting the (web) application (assuming they do use the same database).

Comment: Have a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442564/avoid-synchronizedthis-in-java?rq=1

Answer (score 6):

The *real* answer here: step back and do some studying. You should not be using *synchronized* here, but rather look into a **lock** object that a reader/writer needs to acquire **prior** turning to that "DB class". See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/newlocks.html) for more information.

On the other hand, you should understand what **transactions** are, and how your database supports those. Meaning: there are different kinds of problems; and the different layers (application code, database) have different **responsibilities**.

You see, using "trial and error" isn't an approach that will work out here. You should spend some *serious* time studying the underlying concepts. Otherwise you are risking to damage your data set; and worse: you risk writing code that works fine most of the time; but fails in obscure ways "randomly". Because that is what happens when multiple threads manipulate shared data in an uncontrolled manner.

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstood how `synchronized` work.

If you mark two method of class by `synchronized` only one of them could be executed at any moment of time (except if you invoke `wait`).

Also note that if you have several instances of this class you can execute methods of different instances simultaneously.

Comment: thanks, hmm, so you are saying it won't break? I have only 1 instance of Database class. You sure I don't need any lock mechanisms?

Comment: Yes. It is enough to put `synchronized` on all method that access or modify object state. It isn't best approach, but it is simplest one.

Comment: In general, just sticking `synchronized` on things without consideration or thought will not make it magically thread-safe or behave 'correctly'.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yes of corse. Doing anything "without consideration or thought" never lead to anything good.

Answer (score 0):

@Test(singleThreaded = true) Use above annotation above class and its tests will be run using a single thread even though you have used parallel="methods" in your testng.xml file