# Even with synchronized block getting a duplicate value

Tags: java

my class has a method as follow :

```
private volatile String currentSeqSecondBucket = "";
private volatile int currentUriSeq = 0;

public String calculateRepositoryURI(Date now, String userSpecifiedFolder)
{
  String folder = userSpecifiedFolder;

  if (StringUtils.isBlank(folder))
    folder = RSIConstant.CONTENT_ROOT_FOLDER;

  StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(folder);

  if (!folder.endsWith("/"))
    buf.append("/");

  String nowStr = YYYYMMDDHHMMSS_FORMAT.format(now);

  buf.append(String.valueOf((int)(Math.random() * 1000)));
  buf.append("/");
  buf.append(nowStr);
  buf.append("_"); 


  synchronized (this)// here the this means my class
  {
    if (currentSeqSecondBucket.equals(nowStr))
    {
      currentUriSeq++;
    }
    else
    {
      currentUriSeq = 1;
      currentSeqSecondBucket = nowStr;
    }
    buf.append(String.valueOf(currentUriSeq));
  }

  buf.append(".xml");

  return buf.toString();
}
```

Will this code return a unique string for every call?

Comment: There could be many things which could have caused the duplication. Like `currentUriSeq` being accessible from other threads. Request you to provide the whole code of your's to analyze

Comment: @sidgate If you edit a post, please fix all the problems with it

Comment: why are you synchronizing on `this` - `this` is a different object for each thread.

Comment: It doesn't return anything :P If the question is if currentUriSeq can become larger than 1, yes, if two subsequent nowStr are equal.

Comment: Quite obviously this code will not always return a unique value, because there is a conditional statement which reset it back to 1.

Comment: @ScaryWombat huh? It's perfectly reasonable to synchronize on `this`. If what you were saying were true, there would be no reason to ever synchronize on it.

Comment: @Michael Sorry, based on the lack of code, you are correct.  I was maybe mis-reading that the OP wanted to prevent mutliple Threads calling `one` method overwriting the value of a variable.  Still https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442564/avoid-synchronizedthis-in-java is an interesting read

Comment: @ScaryWombat Indeed, that's why Lombok has [`@Synchronized`](https://projectlombok.org/features/Synchronized)

Comment: well, we have no idea what `this` and all the *variables* or *fields* are. Please consider posting a [mcve]. Also your question is pretty open, and here the answer: "no, it will not return unique `currentUriSeq` - it is conditionally being set to `1` (even for same `nowStr` if there was a call with a different `nowStr` in between)

Answer (score 0):

> Will this code return a unique string for every call?

No.  It won't.  But the reason is nothing to do with thread safety.

The reason is that *occasionally* you may get the same random number generated twice in the same second.  Now if the same random number was generated twice in a row, then your test  `currentSeqSecondBucket.equals(nextStr)` would catch this and you would increment `currentUriSeq` and avoid the collision.  However, a *more* likely scenario is that the random number repeats after more than one call in the same second.  That will *defeat* your test.

My advice would be to not try to re-invent the wheel:

- If you want non-guessable unique names, use the `UUID` class to give you uniqueness.
- If you don't care about guessability, just use a simple sequence number; e.g. implemented using `AtomicInteger` or `AtomicLong`.