# Is using synchronized(this) in object in Kotlin the correct way

Tags: android, kotlin, thread-safety

I have a piece of code I need to lock so that only one thread can enter the critical area at a time.
My program is written in Kotlin and run on Android.

I have declared a singleton like so

```
object MySingleton {
   fun critical() {
      synchronized(this) {
         // critical section here
      }
   }
}
```

My question is - is this correct in that this will definitely only allow just one thread in?

Comment: Many of the concerns expressed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442564/avoid-synchronizedthis-in-java also apply to Kotlin objects.