# Is synchronized keyword in java merely syntax sugar?

Tags: java, syntax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [synchronized block vs synchronized method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574240/synchronized-block-vs-synchronized-method)

Hi all I was wondering is Snippet-A simply a syntax sugar for Snippet-B? :

<sub>Snippet A:</sub>

```
public synchronized void F() {
    //..code
}
```

<sub>Snippet B:</sub>

```
public void F() {
    synchronized (this) {
        //..code
    }
}
```

Or rather, what exactly is the difference between the two pieces of code above?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574240/synchronized-block-vs-synchronized-method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two are identical. See [§8.4.3.6](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.4.3.6) of the [Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/j3TOC.html) (JLS):

> A `synchronized` method acquires a monitor before it executes.
>   [...]
>   For an instance method, the
>   monitor associated with `this` (the object for which the method was
>   invoked) is used.

In the example in the JLS, this:

```
synchronized void bump() { count++; }
```

is said to have the same effect as this:

```
void bump() {
    synchronized (this) {
        count++;
    }
}
```

and your two `F` methods are very similar to the example `bump` methods.