# Why synchronized block is used in System.out.println, instead of synchronized method?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I checked implementation of System.out.println(), which is as follows and I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574240/is-there-an-advantage-to-use-a-synchronized-method-instead-of-a-synchronized-blo) question.

```
public void println(int x) {
    synchronized (this) {
        print(x);
        newLine();
    }
}
```

According to above implementation the lock is on `this` object, **so what is the advantage of using synchronized block instead of synchronized method *in the above case*?**

Comment: As far as I know, I dont see any difference using synchronized method or block as we are locking on 'this'.  Its upto the author I guess

Comment: I could also imagine some form of abstraction, because a synchronized method is directly visible as such to the developer, but a synchronized block is in a deeper layer of visibility so to say.

Comment: There _is_ an advantage in using sync-block in that you have finer control over what you lock against (something finer-grained than `self`). However, that's irrelevant for this _particular_ case. In any case, the dupe-link details all that.

Comment: @paxdiablo nice, that you point out things (s)he already mentioned in the first sentence ...

Comment: @ceekay, assuming you meant the first commenter, I took the opportunity to expand on it since, though it points out no advantage _here,_ there _is_ an advantage in some cases. In fact, I prefer blocks since I'm used to the fine-grained control you get in pthreads, where locks are more on general resources rather than code sections (though you can certainly _use_ a piece of code as a resource). But the _main_ purpose of my comment was to explain my close-vote.

Answer (score 0):

No advantage. They result in the same bytecode and are completely interchangeable.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I am thinking if developer had anything in mind while implementing `println` method.